# Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have one value of some tuple type, and I want to map it to a different tuple of a different type. The tuples are allowed to be heterogenous. Is there a way of performing this mapping without using the type cast in the example below?

```js
interface SomeType<T> {
  value: T
}

type SomeTypeList<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]: SomeType<T[K]> }

interface OtherType<T> {
  otherValue: T
}

type OtherTypeList<T extends any[]> = { [K in keyof T]: OtherType<T[K]> }

function convertValues<T extends any[]> (arr: SomeTypeList<T>): OtherTypeList<T> {
  // Is there any way to write this without the cast?
  return arr.map(({ value }) => ({ otherValue: value })) as OtherTypeList<T>
}

convertValues<[number, string, boolean]>([{ value: 1 }, { value: 'cat' }, { value: true }])
// => [{ otherValue: 1 }, { otherValue: 'cat' }, { otherValue: true }]
```

With the cast it loses type safety, as the callback could instead return `({ otherValue: 1 })` and everything would type check properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible in TypeScript as of TS4.1.  There are two issues I see; one might be overcome with a change to the TypeScript standard library typings for [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but the other would require a fairly large change to the type system to work in general and cannot currently be handled in a way that isn't, in some sense, equivalent to a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) (what you're calling a "cast").

---

The [current library typings](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7de5d0b83a2100e3729470b76846a4bb36e1b30e/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1361) for the `map()` method of an array is:

```
interface Array<T> {
  map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

The return type, `U[]` is an unordered array type corresponding to the output type of the `callbackfn` argument.  It is not a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).  There is an open GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841) asking to change this so that when you call `map()` on a tuple, you get a tuple of the same length out.  It is not currently implemented; but you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) to test such a change out for yourself:

```
// declare global { // uncomment if in a module
interface Array<T> {
  map<This extends Array<T>, U>(this: This, fn: (v: T) => U): { [K in keyof This]: U }
}
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  map<This extends ReadonlyArray<T>, U>(
    this: This, fn: (v: T) => U): { [K in keyof This]: U }
}
// }
```

If I call `convertValues()` (with a change to the `arr` parameter as a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) which gives the compiler a hint that it should interpret `arr` as a tuple if possible), you can see how it now knows how many elements are in the return value:

```
function convertValues<T extends any[]>(arr: [...SomeTypeList<T>]) {
  return arr.map(({ value }) => ({ otherValue: value }))
}

const ret = convertValues([{ value: 1 }, { value: 'cat' }, { value: true }])
ret[0]; ret[1]; ret[2]; // okay
ret[3] // error! Tuple type of length '3' has no element at index '3'.
```

Unfortunately, the *types* of each tuple element are not known:

```
ret[0].otherValue.toFixed(2); // error!
// -------------> ~~~~~~~
// Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean'.
```

Each element is only known to the compiler to be `{otherValue: string | number | boolean}`.  This isn't incorrect, but also isn't what you're looking for.

---

So let's step back and think about what you'd need `map()` to be like for this to do what you want. When you call `arr.map()`, you're thinking of the callback as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function that turns an input of a generic type `SomeType<V>` to an output of type `OtherType<V>`, for any `V`.  Otherwise there's no chance of getting the compiler to notice the correlation between each element of the input tuple and the corrsponding element of the output tuple.  You can indeed write that when you call `map()` by annotating the callback:

```
function convertValues<T extends any[]>(arr: [...SomeTypeList<T>]) {
  return arr.map(<V,>(
    { value }: SomeType<V>
  ): OtherType<V> => ({ otherValue: value }))
}
```

The problem is... how do you describe such generic callbacks in general which might do something else?  I presume you don't want to hardcode the typing for `map()` to care about callbacks that specifically turn `SomeType<V>` into `OtherType<V>`.  You want to say "callbacks that turn `F<X>` into `G<X>` for any `F` and `G`":

```
// not valid TypeScript, don't use it
interface Array<T> {
  map<A extends any[], F<?>, G<?>>(
    this: { [K in keyof A]: F<A[K]>},
    fn: <V>(v: F<V>) => G<V>
  ): { [K in keyof A]: G<A[K]> }
}
```

But **there is no way to express this in TypeScript**. `F` and `G` above are not generic *types*, but generic *type functions* or *type constructors*.  And these do not exist in TypeScript.  Generic type constructors would require introduction of so-called [higher kinded types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) as can be found in some more functional-programming-heavy languages like Haskell and Scala.  There is a longstanding open feature request, [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) asking for this, but who knows if it will ever be implemented.  It would be quite a bit of work, so I'm not holding my breath (but would love to see it!). and there are some possible ways to simulate higher kinded types in TypeScript (you can read that GitHub issue for more), but nothing I'd want to recommend for your use case.

So we're stuck.  There's currently no way to write `map()`'s typing to get the compiler to verify that `convertValues()`'s implementation conforms to the type you claim to return.

---

And when the compiler can't verify that the type of something is what you claim it is, and you're confident that your claim is nevertheless correct, you pretty much need to do something like a type assertion, as you've already done.  So I'd recommend you keep doing it the way you've shown here, and revisit if higher kinded types ever show up in TypeScript.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=41&ssc=5&pln=35&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gFDLIC2cADvgBbADOyEAHpCACYvqa6EANMgCqBABRhGTAFzI804TBBzxANzl4AlMgC8REVrnFkAbQDSyUMgDWELAHsY86QF05I5AF9SP0qVBIWEQUAGUHSgg8LBoIfCIyCjU4ABsAVwhNX38wGLCIqLyAGWYwfFYOCG4WOBAsU1ciXRIzS2s7R2c8d2RwyOjY-AtG739A6HgkZAB5KWgBuMIScmQHOagANVSMrL9c2Jn1hZKmMrwKzh5kWvqR5pMLKxBbeyd5Htn6ebyh8xG-GBpEAIMDABzPBDgtTQMBbdIQJjldiXGp1BoSOAYOSmAB0eL6hViJzOBFcOkSyCgEDAaSgz0xUBx1Bo4hwG0EEhWFBMyXh3jkBIWbIIKyMhy+UCFGyaRHEJjWErhO2QvIy3i0WmypEhIFOlOpemQOuhUFh2wR4lMPPNcgAjN5hNb4XIAOQIOBgF0OlqqzLIMBQNVeMmkKlgUwABlcAG59eHbTG46YAEyJgD0adWNmwoeppgAzK5kBnWBgHFAAITyNI0FIofYoN51kAAcykyBd+a99DgLBADlYdci4GuYCeXHYHa7OP8ufDUZxCugSogOLADgAYsA2BAuOJk1pYyXoFByxXSCWALTXm+3m9EAB+T+fD4vmYACqfYqasB311udy4L0uAcBFkH7Md2FKVZngbDtTigUAW2QAAfcC0koAAjaBUOQTCHAcOtahdGdZxLUJpl6VAABFkAAYVQAA5RjpnOajKLwAAJABJUJkEAXg3AH49i8AConiCSYUD4bB4mWChmRwVALiqK4bgaYQNxwAB+AhhAAfQAcW0ghOQoCgpGYYxHnaV5nFQHpNNQYYCC8QQuWQZQ5GFdQ5E06UdH0ZAjOlUVjFaJ4Xk6NAeiMpy-iIHwvGQES0yAA)