# Generic zip in typescript, using variadc tuple

Tags: typescript, generics, variadic-tuple-types

I have a background in python, and I enjoy playing with functional languages, and I'm learning typescript, so I'd like to have a `zip()` function that works somewhat like Python's. I see the typescript has gained both generators and variadic generics, so I think this should be possible. I have something that is *very* close to what I want, but it's not quite. I'm sure I'm either doing something obvious, or I'm about to learn the deep workings of the typescript type system.

What I want is a function that takes a variable number of arrays, and yields a tuple of elements from those arrays until the shortest array is exhausted. I wrote a generator that does that, but I'm having trouble getting the typing right.

```js
  function* zip<T extends any[]>(...args: T) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(...args.map((e) => { return e.length })); ++i) {
      yield args.map((e) => { return e[i]; }) as T;
    }
  }
```

If I remove the `as T` then the function works, but I lose all type information, if not then I get A return type `[...T[]]`, but I want `[...T]`.

For example, `zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])`, should have a return type  of `[number, string]`, but it has `[number[], string[]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want typings that look something like this:

```
function* zip<T extends any[][]>(...args: T) {
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(...args.map((e) => { return e.length })); ++i) {
        yield args.map((e) => { return e[i]; }) as
            { [I in keyof T]: T[I][number] };
    }
}
```

Note that you want `args` to be an array *of arrays*, right?  Each element of `args` should itself have a `length` property and have elements accessible via numeric indices.  So `T extends any[][]` will do that for you (you might even want to loosen it up so that it accepts [`readonly` arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) also, but I won't get into that.)

You don't want to return `T` for each element yielded by the generator, since that's an array of arrays.  If you don't annotate the return then you get whatever the compiler thinks `map()` produces, which is necessarily going to be less precise than what you're looking for (see [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091118/mapping-tuple-typed-value-to-different-tuple-typed-value-without-casts) for more information).  You have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) the type, but it's not `T`.

Instead, for each numeric index `I` in the indices of `T`, you want to take the array type `T[I]` at that index and return the *element type* of that array.  We can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to represent this transformation, because [mapped types on tuples produce tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  That's what `{ [I in keyof T]: T[I][number] }` does.

Okay, let's test it:

```
for (const z of zip([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])) {
    console.log(z[0].toFixed(2) + ", " + z[1].toUpperCase())
    // "1.00, A" "2.00, B" "3.00, C"
}
```

Looks good; the compiler sees that `z` is `[number, string]` and lets you treat each element of `z` accordingly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mAVAAgF4wA4B4AqyCmAHlPmACYDOyAhmAJ4DaAuswHwAUAdN9QE4DmFAFzIcASmQBvAFDI5yYHF7J2AG3xRkMZAF5kABgDcW5FmQBZalAAWnALYwwXHgIr3qGdu3wSdrKci8GiC8YASc6mD8NsgAvmJixgDUSTASMvKZyHQw+KpkNK7unt6+-pKBwaEEDDBMxvE0FLJZrRUMAJJaYQDW+HRwwKJMIjidLGAgdgBG+LxMcYYtcrHSq9KKyuwQCBSaqMiDaJjsDACMADTIAExXAMxMVwwA5NTPV8-T78jPEM9MCSky2QOzAFDg6gicH47FQDH0TE4UDgADEYIR8GR2NcJElkAAiK745B4uFnRHIgCqGAwcwAwtQKPh2AlgQB6NkEs6cfT6K4AQWJ+OuPL5yAAQkK7qKrnT8WtpNIgA)