# Can a mapped tuple preserve the length and ordering of typed entries in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary, tuples, mapped-types

In this code example, the `expandedMappedTuple` does the same operation as the `looseMappedTuple`.

However, the `looseMappedTuple` has lost all information regarding the length and tuple sequence.

Is there a `MappedTupleType` which can fix this which could be added to the draft mapping code which follows, and cast the return value of `.map` with extra information from the original readonly tuple?

Alternatively is there another way to ensure `strictMappedTuple` has the same type as `expandedMappedTuple`?

Unlike with https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091730/2257198 the mapping is defined in `MappedType` and can be baked into the `mapTuple` function, (no higher-order types needed) and I am happy to use type assertions when the facts are so certain - I don't expect it to be inferred.

However, I've tried a lot of ways to define MappedTupleType and so far failed.

This is a deliberately toy example representing a real world problem from a list of constants I want to transform, preserving type and length.

```
type MappedType<T extends string> = `£${T}`;

function prefixCurrencyString<T extends string>(value: T): MappedType<T> {
  return `£${value}`;
}

const letters = ["a", "b", "c"] as const;

// Type of this const is correctly 
// readonly ["£a", "£b", "£c"]
// with length and ordering
const expandedMappedTuple = [
  prefixCurrencyString(letters[0]),
  prefixCurrencyString(letters[1]),
  prefixCurrencyString(letters[2]),
] as const;

// Type of this const is sadly
// ("£a" | "£b" | "£c")[]
// without length or ordering
const looseMappedTuple = letters.map(prefixCurrencyString);


/** TRY AND FIX IT */

// The aim of this type would be to 'cast' the array returned from .map
// as used in mapTuple() below

type MappedTupleType<Tup extends [...string[]]> = {
  [Index in keyof Tup]: MappedType<Tup[Index]>;
} & {length: Tup['length']}

function mapTuple<
  Tup extends Readonly<[...string[]]>,
  Fn extends <T extends string>(t: T) => MappedType<T>
>(list: Tup, fn: Fn) {
  const mappedList = list.map(fn);
  type Arr = typeof mappedList;
  return mappedList as MappedTupleType<Tup>;
}


// Type of this const should be 
// readonly ["£a", "£b", "£c"]
// just like expandedMappedTuple
const strictMappedTuple = mapTuple(letters, prefixCurrencyString);
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZb6Pm)

Comment: Something like https://tsplay.dev/wEGrZm ?

Comment: That is exactly right. Now I need to find what's different compared to the way I approached it! I thought I'd fathomed somewhere else that extends [...something[]] preserved tuple nature but looks like that makes no difference. Looks like the `& string` resolves an important error I was facing.

Comment: In https://tsplay.dev/Ndd6kN I reintroduced the narrower type on the function definition, as this potentially eliminates incorrect casts (where the result is actually not sure to be of MappedType). An (x:string) => string is potentially too broad and would let in some runtime errors. But other than that I can run with this!