# How do I create a new tuple from a variadic generic tuple in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, tuples

Given:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar {}

interface QueryResult<T> {
  data: T;
}

function creatQueryResult<T>(data: T): QueryResult<T> {
  return {data};
}

function tuple<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T {
  return args;
}
```

I want to create and type a function using inferred types that accepts `QueryResult[]` or a tuple of `QueryResult`s and a factory callback that picks `data` and invokes the callback like:

```
function createCompoundResult<T>(
  queryResults: T,
  callback: (queryResultDatas: ???<T>) => any
) {
  const datas = queryResults.map((queryResult) => queryResult.data);

  return callback(datas);
}
```

Note the `???` in the above code.

Usage:

```
const fooQueryResult = creatQueryResult(new Foo());
const barQueryResult = creatQueryResult(new Bar());

// Maybe using tuples are wrong?
const queryResults = tuple(fooQueryResult, barQueryResult);

createCompoundResult(
  queryResults,
  (datas) => {
    const [foo, bar] = datas;
    // foo should be inferred as Foo here and bar as Bar
  }
);
```

Maybe tuples are the wrong way to go? How would you solve it?

I'm a bit of a TypeScript newbie and I have a really hard time understanding stuff like `keyof`, `extends keyof`, `{ [K in keyof T]: { a: T[K] } }` so if your solutions include arcane magic like this, please explain it to me like I'm 5 years old.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrKV1m) work for your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining it (although any explanation I give would be unlikely to help a kindergartner).  If not, let me know what I'm missing

Comment: @jcalz That works like a charm. Thank you very much. Be sure to add it as an answer so I can mark and point it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion for `createCompoundResult()` is this:

```
function createCompoundResult<T extends any[]>(
  queryResults: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: QueryResult<T[I]> }],
  callback: (queryResultDatas: readonly [...T]) => any
) {
  const datas = queryResults.map((queryResult) => queryResult.data) as T;
  return callback(datas);
}
```

The function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, corresponding to the tuple of arguments to `callback`.  In order to describe the type of `queryResults` in terms of the array/tuple type `T`, we want to [map it to another array/tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) where for each numeric index `I` of `T`, the element type `T[I]` gets mapped to `QueryResult<T[I]>`.  So if `T` is `[string, number]`, then we want `queryResults` to be of type `[QueryResult<string>, QueryResult<number>]`.

You can do this via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  It looks like `{ [I in keyof T]: QueryResult<T[I]> }`.  For array-like generic types `T`, mapped types like `[I in keyof T]` only iterate over the numeric-like keys `I` (and skip all the other array keys like `"push"` and `"length"`).  So you can imagine  `{ [I in keyof T]: QueryResult<T[I]> }` acting on a `T` of `[string, boolean]` operating on `I` being `"0"` and then `"1"`, and `T["0"]` is `string` and `T["1"]` is `boolean`, so you get `{0: QueryResult<string>, 1: QueryResults<boolean>}`, which is [magically interpreted as a new tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `[QueryResult<string>, QueryResult<boolean>]`.

That's the main explanation, although there are a few outstanding things to mention.

---

First is that the compiler does not know that [the array `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will turn a tuple into a tuple, and it *definitely* doesn't know that `queryResult => queryResult.data` will turn a tuple of type `{ [I in keyof T]: QueryResult<T[I]> }` into a tuple of type `T`. ([See this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218).)  It sees the output type of your `queryResults.map(...)` line as `T[number][]`, meaning: some array of the element types of `T`.  It has lost length and order information.  So we have to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that the output of `queryResults.map(...)` is of type `T`, so that `datas` can be passed to `callback`.

Next, there are a few places where I've wrapped an array type `AAA` in `readonly [...AAA]`.  This uses [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax to give the compiler a hint that we'd like it to infer tuple types instead of array types.  If you don't use that, then something like `[fooQueryResult, barQueryResult]` will tend to be inferred as an array type `Array<QueryResult<Foo> | QueryResult<Bar>>` instead of the desired tuple type `[QueryResult<Foo>, QueryResult<Bar>]`.  Using this syntax frees us from needing to use a `tuple()` helper function, at least if you pass the array literal directly.

---

Anyway, let's make sure it works:

```
class Foo { x = 1 }
class Bar { y = 2 }

createCompoundResult(
  [fooQueryResult, barQueryResult],
  (datas) => {
    const [foo, bar] = datas;
    foo.x
    bar.y
  }
);
```

Looks good.  I gave some structure to `Foo` and `Bar` (it's always [recommended](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) to do so even for example code) and sure enough, the compiler understands that `datas` is a tuple whose first element is a `Foo` and whose second element is a `Bar`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG9oA9oF5oEZoF8BYAKFEhgCEwAnFaATy2gCYCSSBLAOwBcBTagDMwwPtACKAVwH0ASnwiSQPADwAVAHwoS0aABMwPMAC5oagNwkixEoMldgPDvC7Rg1Pob5SZ8xcvUNAAoDI1M1AEpTH2o5BSVVTW1iXQ8eSWpXVFCwAktia1t7R2dXd09+AGF4AFsAB3h7PT8E9Wg+NH4uPRgwLnoAbQBdYJ1oAEdpWJblCFMPMD0XEEYBgDoN1AGASWhuaABrPnp4QTMh6Km4-0SdkYIhgBox4DAQEAAjEQPTIMnfeLKAAihkg808Sy4K2g6w2aiGESwWj69BIiOQLxcEB4+lBMGw-2mgJ4EDWNTAdSCfyuMx4iMwWkJ1wSaxyiMgZnyqT46Uybjen2+ITxEXyhVIWJxgkQMWZyiY5S8stpQS4fAA7nBEEEIqKSMBJdAvtRlcSFQt+KabqqNdAqNQdXqbKQLXxqvVGt0VWMBtL4FaEo8jTQA8onmNhUYIPStBiUro3IbfYgg8ahkwchAuQm-Ws0GNdMa1qj49ZRUA)