# Type a function as such it does return an array of same length

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Is there a way to type a function so it says "I take an array of generic type, and will return the same type with the same length"

```ts
interface FixedLengthArray<T, L extends number> extends Array<T> {
  length: L;
}

export function shuffle<T, Arr extends Array<T>>(array: Arr):FixedLengthArray<T, Arr['length']> {
  const copy: T[] = [...array];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [copy[i], copy[j]] = [copy[j], copy[i]];
  }

  return copy;
}

function isPairComplete<T>(arr: T[]): arr is [T, T] {
  return arr.length === 2
}

const checkThis: (pair: [number, number]) => void = ([one, two]) => {
  //
}

checkThis(shuffle([1, 2]))
```

Here is a [link to Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAB4QCYBkIgDmYAFgIJRRwCeAPACoA0yuyEGkI2AzsiAK4BbAEbQAfGw4EeyClTr0JAbwBQyZABsCxEgC4WAbhUBfFSvYAHAPZQwyGPxAIwwKyGTcS-GDC0NmcpKcMnI0DGJiABRwlDT6cgCUuuhYeNqkoQoBlADaAORaRKR5ALrKasgIbtx2VRbU+vQ5JcgAvMg5AHTdMfIlRuowNsiRWnbAbci9NJ2FOsgAtMgAjAbIExIADGsTC+3LCciq6upVIDXIAFaTALJwpJ2+VjaRdw9UXFaCkYcAVCMTADUKwSCQGJxydWoOWAJWYUJylxKLXakKs9URcMq6OhsP6FVMFSgEDA-Cg7ihRkJDicLjc624AAU4MAoABhL4WMYQcLRSiNZpJKaUBkdJjIegtY7IYmk8nCqCzdIkNqtdoAJhMZjOFwQJAgCAA1vQSMBuPpIhYWVB9DkBCJoMx7aIoCVDq0JAA3KzAbCTSI5NwQZhgADuVjdbXK6gA9DGtSo9QbjabuJFPN5fBAA8tmOq3QkgA)

I still have a doubt on whether I'm trying to use the good thing. Maybe the solution is to reuse the same type `FixedLengthArray` to type my function `checkThis`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGPBVw) work for you?  You can [map generic tuple types to other tuple types of the same length](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), which behaves similarly to what it looks like you're trying to achieve.  If that's acceptable, I can write it up as an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: This is excellent. I guess there's no way to prevent the cast ?

Comment: (I assume by "cast" you mean "[type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)".)  The TypeScript compiler does not have the higher-order reasoning ability to verify that a generic type `T extends any[]` is assignable to `{[I in keyof T]: T[number]}`.  So you will either need a type assertion or some other type safety hole to stop the compiler from complaining.

Comment: So should I write up an answer here or am I missing anything about the question?

Comment: You're totally fine, I'll accept this with pleasure !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can try to describe your own fixed-length array types by providing a numeric [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) to its `length` property, the compiler won't really be able to do much with it.  It is probably better to just use [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), which already represent fixed-length array types.

If `shuffle()` takes a value of some array/tuple type `T` and produces a new array containing the same elements in some random order, then one way we can describe the return type is like this:

```
type Shuffled<T extends any[]> = { [I in keyof T]: T[number] };
```

When you make a [mapped type over array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), the result is another array/tuple type of the same length.  And in this instance we're saying that each element of the resulting tuple will have the type of *some* element from the initial tuple.  The type `T[number]` means "the type of the value stored at a `number` index of the `T` type", which will end up being the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of any element-specific types.  So if you pass a *heterogeneous* tuple like `[string, number]` in, you will get a *homogeneous* tuple of the same length like `[string | number, string | number]` out.

Let's test how it behaves:

```
type Test1 = Shuffled<[number, number, number]>;
// type Test1 = [number, number, number]

type Test2 = Shuffled<[string, number, string]>;
// type Test2 = [string | number, string | number, string | number]

type Test3 = Shuffled<Date[]>
// type Test3 = Date[]
```

Looks good. Note that for `Test3`, a non-tuple array like `Date[]` stays the same; if the compiler doesn't know the input length, the output length is also unknown.

---

Now we can give your `shuffle()` implementation a more fitting typing:

```
function shuffle<T extends any[]>(array: [...T]) {
  const copy = [...array];
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 1) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [copy[i], copy[j]] = [copy[j], copy[i]];
  }
  return copy as Shuffled<T>;
}

const shuffled = shuffle([1, 2, 3]);
// const shuffled: [number, number, number]

const alsoShuffled = shuffle([1, "", false]);
// const alsoShuffled: [string | number | boolean, 
//   string | number | boolean, string | number | boolean]
```

Everything works as expected here, but a few notes:

First: in order to prompt the compiler to notice `shuffle([1, 2, 3])` as operating on a tuple instead of an array, I have given the `array` function parameter the [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...T]` instead of just `T`.  If you remove that, you'll end up having to do other tricks to get the desired behavior (such as your `checkThis()` function to contextually require a tuple).

Second: the compiler is not clever enough to perform the sort of type analysis necessary to verify that the implementation of `shuffle()` actually takes an `array` of type `[...T]` and produces a result of type `Shuffled<T>`.  Therefore I have used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that `copy` can be treated `as Shuffled<T>` when it is returned.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgVwGZIDYQCYB4AqUIAewEAdhgM5QCGJIA2gLoB8UAvFAN5R0CSUAliSgBrCCAD2SKDgYAuaXRIIAtgCMIAJwZQAvgG4AUAdCRpEcsACMbWIhTpsileo0AaKErWb3nl80MA9AFQJtA45lY2Tl5uHs7ecTEMRqFmFgBMNvDIaJhYdBYaggDmPvGxhSX+BkEh4GERmewFwEUkxVAAPoku7pXtXT0J-R3dvprJxvVpwADMWXa52AAiVMSMTDXBqeEW8+yr65NICCQAxsD84kLki+i4+ESkFNS0GwAUVBoaVCDydAA6IEyACUnAMUCgZ2uFih4jAICiQIBXx+IAYhkhSHEGig73QwAENlRvwB6HawDgUAAtFBLHoiSwAAwM-g09iWMEcCGQuEkWEAKxsAFk1nAAWhxDj3qLKQCfmRxMp3mCAFR4tkAajpIJBmN5dGhCLo-AY7iN9AFDG0zQtdCt5vh9FNGJ5Oh5GggwAQGiEFuolGy9jyOCYhndBmh-MJtxyDhsseD7zolnc6XcswYeq2fNhiaW-3GsSLZSSRijsKoqHI4iDSwTdwgydTUAARK33Egq+QIFnAsEK4Tu7XGxh-iNBkXBqopegaH1WiVJ+Vp7OIPOoBOxivujPxHOSAwgA)

Comment: what if the returning elements inside of the array need to be of a different type?

Comment: @CrisPinto Not possible in general, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218 . Maybe your particular use case is possible but a comment on an existing answer isn't a great place to explore that.  Good luck!