# TypeScript: Is it possible to define a variadic function that accepts different types of arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, types

I want to write a generic function that accepts variable number of arguments that may have different types and returns a tuple based on those arguments.

Here is an example in JavaScript:

```js
function evaluate (...fns) {
  return fns.map(fn => fn())
}

evaluate(
  () => 10
) // [ 10 ]

evaluate(
  () => 10,
  () => 'f',
  () => null
) // [ 10, 'f', null ]
```

And in TypeScript I need to somehow convert the spread argument tuple to a resulting one:

```js
function evaluate<T1, T2 ... Tn> (
  ...fns: [() => T1, () => T2 ... () => Tn]
): [T1, T2 ... Tn] {
  return fns.map(fn => fn()) as [T1, T2 ... Tn]
}

evaluate(
  () => 10
) // [ 10 ]: [number]

evaluate(
  () => 10,
  () => 'f',
  () => null
) // [ 10, 'f', null ]: [number, string, null]
```

I've tried a naive approach of creating an overload for all reasonable lengths of tuple:

```js
function evaluate<T1> (
  fn1: () => T1
): [T1]
function evaluate<T1, T2> (
  fn1: () => T1,
  fn2: () => T2
): [T1, T2]
function evaluate<T1, T2, T3> (
  fn1: () => T1,
  fn2: () => T2,
  fn3: () => T3
): [T1, T2, T3]
function evaluate<T1, T2, T3> (
  ...fns: Array<(() => T1) | (() => T2) | (() => T3)>
): [T1] | [T1, T2] | [T1, T2, T3] {
  return fns.map(fn => fn()) as [T1] | [T1, T2] | [T1, T2, T3]
}
```

But it looks horribly, doesn't scale well and causes issues with a more complex function body.

Is there any way this could be done dynamically? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use mapped types on tuple/arrays as in [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJqd5m).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer explaining it.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that definitely meets my needs, thank you! Answer with an explanation would be useful too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to implement this is to make `evaluate()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in its arraylike output type `T` (intended to be a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)),  and then represent the `fns` rest parameter as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) on `T`, noting that [mapped array/tuple types are also array/tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays):

```
function evaluate<T extends any[]>(
  ...fns: { [I in keyof T]: () => T[I] }
) {
  return fns.map(fn => fn()) as T;
}
```

Note that the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `as T` is necessary because the compiler cannot see that `fns.map(fn => fn())` will have the effect of converting an array/tuple of function types to the array/tuple of corresponding return types.  See [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218) for more information.

Because `{[I in keyof T]: () => T[I]}` is a *homomorphic* mapped type where we are mapping directly over `keyof T` (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) for more information), the compiler is able to [infer `T` from it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) (linked page is deprecated, but still accurate and no new page exists ‍♂️).

Let's see it in action:

```
const x = evaluate(() => 10);
// const x: [number]

const y = evaluate(
  () => 10,
  () => 'f',
  () => null
)
// const y: [number, string, null]
```

Looks good.  The compiler sees that `x` is of type `[number]` and `y` is of type `[number, string, null]`.  It also behaves reasonably in cases where you pass in a rest argument of unknown order/length:

```
const fs = [() => "a", () => 3];
// const fs: ((() => string) | (() => number))[]

const z = evaluate(...fs);
// const z: (string | number)[]
```

Here  `fs` is of the type `Array<(()=>string) | (()=>number)>`, and so `z` is of the analogous type `Array<string | number>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwG4EMA2J1WQHgBUUAPPMAEwGdF0wBPAbQF0A+ACgChFEA6f4GCoAuRAG9EjAJKIYSANbJ6cYIkLNR7AJSIAvKzXTmiAL6cdY7ogBOyKCGtJBVXgFt0AB3aC9Bwdp10GkIAbk4zTggEKihEEj0UDGxcZHZtX0QARgAGLTCAenzEKKFYklFGMBBXACNka2ZOSOjY+gS0LBw8Lh50-SzsgBorPoMAcmAx4d6dfqrMTHNOQuKWxHoKqtr6wcQY6zkAc135zEamkpjEYBpdSVHEACJ0R92HgGZmAqLL2JvNNKzAz7I46AA+iEBGS2dWsWi0LGapUQAC92kkuql+Lwbnllj81ijNCCwIdEBCYfUEcwgA)