# Use a variadic tuple and infer a callback functions types correctly

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I made a simple example where I have some generic object that wraps a specific type.

Every Object has a value and a function to return that value.

I want to make a function that takes an array of these objects and a callback function. The callback function should be invoked with the value of each of those objects - and infer the order correctly.

Is it possible to achieve this? If it's not possible could someone explain why? I **don't** want to do any type casts.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
type WrapperObject<T> = {
  value: T
  getValue: () => T
}

type UnwrapGeneric<T extends ReadonlyArray<WrapperObject<unknown>>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends WrapperObject<infer V> ? V : never
}

function createWrapperObject<T>(value: T): WrapperObject<T> {
  return {
    value,
    getValue: function (): T {
      return this.value
    },
  }
}

function getValues<T extends ReadonlyArray<WrapperObject<unknown>>>(
  wrapperObjects: [...T],
  callback: (...args: UnwrapGeneric<[...T]>) => void,
) {
  const values = wrapperObjects.map((obj) => obj.getValue())
  callback(...(values as Parameters<typeof callback>)) //TODO: Is it possible to get rid of this typecast?
}

const first = createWrapperObject(5)
const second = createWrapperObject('test')
const third = createWrapperObject([8])

getValues([first, second, third], (valOne, valTwo, valThree) => {
  valOne
  valTwo
  valThree
})
```

As you can see there is one type cast left that I can't seem to get rid off.

Comment: Your two errors are caused by two separate issues (implementation of `getValues()` vs `wrapperObjects` being an unordered array) and the only relationship between them is that they both occur in your code.  As such, this is really two questions in one.  Please [edit] the question to focus on just one of these, and, if necessary, create a question for the other one.

Comment: @jcalz I've made an edit where the array of wrapper objects isn't unordered. I still cant figure out if its possible to get rid of that last type cast.

Comment: No, you will need a type assertion somewhere (The term "cast" is best avoided because it is ambiguous).  TypeScript lacks the expressiveness to represent how `map()` turns a heterogeneous tuple type into a related heterogeneous tuple type performs.  See the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218) for more information.