# How to extend generic tuple in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a function that decorates objects in an array and returns them. The returned type for each item must keep the literals from the generics. Is there a way to do this?

```js
type Identified<Id extends string = string> = { id: Id };
type Extended<Id extends string> = Identified<Id> & { test: "test" };

let one: Identified<"one"> = {id:"one"};
let two: Identified<"two"> = {id:"two"};
let three: Identified<"three"> = {id:"three"};

function extendList<A extends Identified>(arr: A[]) {
  return arr.map((item) => ({ ...item, test: "test" }));
}

let extendedList = extendList([one,two,three]); // literal is lost
let oneExtended = extendedList[0]; // this should be {id:"one", test:"test"} (not {id:string...})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAdsAlgMxROAeeUIAewScAzlKcAE4qIDmUAvBdbXQHxNQDeUKcALlhwoAXwDcAWABQoSFACiREllwjCxRGRY16nZvCSoMq+JwBkPKMUpCARDeB2xU6TIA2EYFAD2iCEKGyOiYOHZ+EHb6PPwC4f52Eh5e1gDuPoEIwSZhwOlRXNyxDvlJ0p7ewAAWVBABwkYhqg41dQXMRYIttZFlMmgArogAxqh++MpaADIolNgAghOa2kHGoewAFACGVFRC8wDaALoAlDwyUFC1wANUiFA7VAB0ALZbYBsbKMQvZ4ycG14T2B3wgLwANNYILYoA5oU4xCcTq5RDJkt4NCo4DNKFxMdNZsANgcIuC8j4ya0IKdxFAAPR0qDuUFULbuPjkdw+Sjo3z+JTLLB4yYIbGEg4ABiOtIZ1iqswoVR8A3cIgARtBOnEInZIY44o5ElANogfN4tZRdHRgU9RCcgA)

Comment: You can certainly create the function and give it typings, but you won't be able to get the compiler to *infer* these typings nor *verify* that the implementation is correct.  It looks  like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6PRGm); does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: that works perfectly! if you post it, I'll mark as answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is

```
function extendList<T extends string[]>(
  arr: [...{ [I in keyof T]: Identified<T[I]> }]
) {
  return arr.map((item) => ({ ...item, test: "test" })) as
    { [I in keyof T]: Extended<T[I]> };
}
```

The idea is to make `extendList()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `id` properties of the elements of the `arr` parameter.  So if you call `extendList([one, two, three])`, `T` should be `["one", "two", "three"]`.

Then the type of the input `arr` is a [mapped tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) that turns each element `T[I]` (the `I`th element of the `T` tuple) into `Identified<T[I]>`, while the output is a mapped tuple that turns each element `T[I]` into `Extended<T[I]>`.

Note that the type of `arr` isn't just the mapped type `{ [I in keyof T]: Identified<T[I]> }`, but has been wrapped in a [variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) of the form `[...{ [I in keyof T]: Identified<T[I]> }]`; this is just to give the compiler a hint that it should tend to infer tuple types over unordered arrays.  Otherwise `extendList([one, two, three])` might have `T` be inferred as `("one" | "two" | "three")[]`, which is not what you want.

Also note that I needed to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that `arr.map(item => ({...item, test: "test"}))` is of the desired output type. The compiler can't infer that automatically, nor can it verify it.  It's essentially beyond the compiler's abilities to "see" that `arr.map(...)` does what you say it does.  See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091730/2887218) for more information about this limitation.

Anyway, let's make sure it behaves as you want:

```
let one: Identified<"one"> = { id: "one" };
let two: Identified<"two"> = { id: "two" };
let three: Identified<"three"> = { id: "three" };
let extendedList = extendList([one, two, three]);
// let extendedList: [Extended<"one">, Extended<"two">, Extended<"three">]
let oneExtended = extendedList[0]; 
// let oneExtended: Extended<"one">
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer. also very helpful for the links to mapped tuple and variadic tuple since those aren't really covered in the handbook https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
type Identified<Id extends string = string> = { id: Id };
type Extended<Id extends string> = Identified<Id> & { test: "test" };

const one: Identified<"one"> = {id:"one"};
const two: Identified<"two"> = {id:"two"};
const three: Identified<"three"> = {id:"three"};

function extendList<T extends string>(arr: Identified<T>[]): Extended<T>[] {
  return arr.map((item) => ({ ...item, test: "test" }));
}

const extendedList = extendList([one,two,three]);
const oneExtended = extendedList[0];
```

Comment: unfortunately this creates a union: `Extended<"one" | "two" | "three">`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone also needs to derive a tuple type from a generic tuple see the `ExtensibleList` below:

```js
type Identified<Id extends string = string> = { id: Id };
type ExtensibleList<List, Extension> = {
  [I in keyof List]: List[I] & Extension;
};

let one: Identified<"one"> = {id:"one"};
let two: Identified<"two"> = {id:"two"};
let three: Identified<"three"> = {id:"three"};
const list = [one,two,three] as const;

type ExtendedIdList = ExtensibleList<typeof list,{test:"test"}>

let extendedList:ExtendedIdList = [{id:"one", test:"test"}, {id:"two", test:"test"}, {id:"three",test:"test"}];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAdsAlgMxROAeeUIAewScAzlKcAE4qIDmUAvBdbXQHxNQDeUKcALlhwoAXwDcAWABQoSFACiRJKRQAjADYQAMikrZdlADSLliVQHtEnZtxlQoAbRh9EUANYQQFtFEPAAXSF-ZwCoADJTYnMUKylpCRkZLWAoKwgheCRUDCxsACJ0-JsefgFCxAh8xOkUqGAAdwtMhGR0TBx8xotirm4yrqbq+LrgAAsqCAzhbPa8romp3tsB8cmqmoBjK0ooDT1U5kd0o27TxYgwgENybfNgeJk5aCVohDh4fy5XlXUtf2wzx8ewORm4xEo5QhwGq7CStQgqUIbyw-gEP0Q70+By4jn6ggqVRM0KhEEo1RM+KhQ2JZOApPJokpqwu+VOdIZMNEAXEQA)

this is because an [Arrays are objects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) with numeric keys and [mapped tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) were added in TS 3.1+