# Specify map return value for a fixed-length array type

Tags: typescript

I needed to specify an array of specific length and arrived at this:

```js
export type Dozen<T extends any = any> = Readonly<[
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T,
    T
]>
```

However, I'd like like `dozen.map( (v)=>AnotherType )` to return type `Dozen<AnotherType>` rather than `AnotherType[]`. Right now I can't even cast it — TS complains the map return value may not have the same number of elements.

It feels like I could override map if Dozen were an interface, but it doesn't seem possible to use an interface to set numeric key types, i.e.

```js
interface Dozen<T> extends Array<any> {
    [0]:T
    [1]:T
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: See [ms/TS#29841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29841) and the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091118/mapping-tuple-typed-value-to-different-tuple-typed-value-without-casts) for more information.  You could merge a custom `map()` call signature into `Array` and `ReadonlyArray` to make tuples come out, as long as they all have the same element type, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2arW).