# TypeScript: type rename keys function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function that takes in a rename function and an object, and renames the object's keys based on the rename function.

```
export default function mapKeys<T extends { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>>(
  renameFunction: (key: string) => string,
  object: T,
): T {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => [renameFunction(key), value]),
  );
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
mapKeys(key => key.toUpperCase(), { a: 1, b: 2 });
// => { A: 1, B: 2 }
```

The problem is, that TypeScript complains about both, the function definition:

```
Type '{ [k: string]: T; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  '{ [k: string]: T; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ [s: string]: T; } | ArrayLike<T>'.
```

as well as the errors for the application:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; b: number; }'.
```

and

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ a: number; b: number; }'.
```

Is there a way to type this function, so these errors compile? Ideally, TypeScript would also be aware of the output shape of the function, e.g. if the `renameFunction` is something like:

```
const rename = (a: string) => `${a}Error`;
```

and the object is:

```
{ email: 'foo' }
```

that then TypeScript knows, the key in the resulting object is `emailError`.

I tried writing the function more generic, like this:

```
export default function mapKeys(
  renameFunction: (key: string) => string,
  object: object,
): object {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => [renameFunction(key), value]),
  );
}
```

This compiles, but TypeScript loses the information about the object keys.

If I have an object like `{ name: 'foo' }` and a rename function like `rename: (a: string) => a + 'Foo'`, TypeScript doesn't know the returned object is of shape `{ nameFoo: string }`.

Comment: This is essentially impossible as far as I know.  Even if you manage to convince the compiler that some callback is of type `<T extends string>(x: string) => \`${T}Foo`\`,  the call signature of `mapKeys()` would need to involve *higher kinded types* as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)... and those are not part of the language.  It's very similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66091730/2887218).

Comment: The closest you can get seems to be to try to simulate/emulate higher kinded types, which involves what looks like a registry, so you basically have to merge your rename function signature into an interface before you can use it, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wE483W)).  It's almost certainly not worth it.

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer explaining more fully. If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

What you need for this case is to define two things, for every `renameFunction` the actual (run-time) implementation and type-level implementation. Of course, you will be limited by the type system, so you can't really denote any arbitrary runtime mapping in the type-system.

So, the `renameFunction` will have this type:

```
type RenameFunction<T extends Renamer> = (x: string) => string
```

where the `T` will be type-level function and the right side is the runtime implementation.

`Renamer`, a part of type-level function implementation will be implemented like this:

```
interface Renamer {
    A: string
    type: string
}
```

where `A` will represent the input type and `type` the output type.

Then, this will be the shape of the actual type-level function:

```
interface UppercaseRenamer extends Renamer {
    type: Uppercase<this["A"]>
}
```

The `type` will be result of `A` field with some type-level function "called" on it.

This is the type-level function declaration, you also need the other side, the point where you call this type-level function.

```
type HigherKind<F extends Renamer, A> = (F & { A: A })["type"]
```

Here, you merge `F` which represents the type-level function and `{A: A}` which represents the argument and extract from the `"type"` field which represents the type-level result. In this way, you emulate higher-kinded types in typescript.

Then, you can use the encoding in the actual function:

```
type Result<T, U extends Renamer> = 
{
    [K in keyof T as HigherKind<U, K>] : T[K]
}

export default function mapKeys<T extends object, U extends Renamer>(
  renameFunction: RenameFunction<U>,
  object: T,
): Result<T, U> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => [renameFunction(key), value]),
  ) as Result<T, U>
}
```

The last part is the runtime implementation, you need the indicate the type-level function in the signature.

```
const uppercase: RenameFunction<UppercaseRenamer> = (x: string) => x.toUpperCase()
```

For his calling:

```
const result = mapKeys(uppercase, {a: "ttt", c: "xxx"})
```

`result` will have type:

```
{
  A: string,
  C: string
}
```

You can also define other function like this:

```
interface RepeatRenamer extends Renamer {
    type: `${this["A"]}${this["A"]}`
}
const repeat: RenameFunction<RepeatRenamer> = (x: string) => `${x}${x}`
const result2 = mapKeys(repeat, {a: "b", c: "d"})
```

Then, the `result` type will be

```
{
  aa: string,
  cc: string
}
```