# How to map to a tuple type?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to map a type like the following:

```js
type ObjectType = {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: boolean;
  prop4: string;
};
```

to the following?

```js
type TupleType = [number, string, boolean, string]
```

I had no luck first converting an object of type `ObjectType` to an array with `Object.values`. The type of the resulting array would evaluate to `(string | number | boolean)[]`. That's not a tuple type, just an array of a union type.

From the comments I learned, if the object would be modified after initially defining it, the order of the properties could change. For that case I would also be able to use a `Map`.

Another possible solution could use an Array of Tuples like the following as a base, to ensure that the order does not change:

```js
type TupleListType = [
  [string, number],
  [string, string],
  [string, boolean],
  [string, string],
];
const argsTupleList: TupleListType = [
  ["prop1", 1],
  ["prop2", "two"],
  ["prop3", true],
  ["prop4", "four"],
]
```

If I'd have a way to convert `argsTupleList` to an array of type `[number, string, boolean, string]`, it would be solved, too.

---

The resulting array needs to have that type, so I can pass it to a function with the spread operator, like `someFunc(...argsTuple)`.
Have a look at this example in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AFXNAvFA3gWACgoowAnAezAEYAuKAOwFcBbOCMgbiJPKoCZ6AZ2BkAlgwDm3YqUpgAzPTgUKAGwgBDBjN7yALMNETpRAL4yiyCgxFRNZSUPrwkqDJCg4CsvjXrUADQ8cgL0AETAAO4U4cG%208kpQokwQ8XpUhlDhAGYUTGRx5paE1rbA9o5CaExgGl6wiCjAAHQAbppqqUIAFA5OAJQyoJ4AglU1ddjJmBQ5lU6TGiU5TAyoYjZQQhQsEABia8h9jnSMrOxkgQuC28ZS1-1JKupaDI%20OWSLiUgN4IWUdhoWmoKJITpIgjcPpIFDD9ENzEQiDs9od1j0Wlj%20tVahpEYQiCNoEsIB5pgBtZhsDjXb4ma4vDTaOn3SQAXRkgIqZC0anGizxEHopPJDQpUMiMTiyTIqWuuXyhU5yMIqIOR0xWN5nQFuKmQyAA).

If I just convert the object to an array with `Object.values(args)` I get:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

Refactoring the function to accept a different format of args is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example which shows the error you're trying to address in the context of code. I don't see any use of the spread operator in your example.

Comment: Objects aren't semantically ordered (they're string keys, so they'll be in _insertion_ order), and the type certainly isn't. But a simple `function extract(obj: ObjectType): [/* tuple */]` could type- and runtime-safely give you something that spreads into positional arguments, rather than just telling the compiler to let you spread the values however they come and hoping for the best.

Comment: Might have been because I was following the wrong track on Object.keys() rather than Object.values() which was my oversight from rushing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Very good point. I would also be fine to start out with a Map instead of an object: `new Map(Object.entries({prop1: 1, prop2: "two", prop3: 3})`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgD11N) work for your "another possible solution" part? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, exactly, brilliant. An explanation would be very much needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the issues of trying to get the TypeScript compiler to know or care about property order in object types (which are many; `keyof` will produce a union, whose order is implementation-defined, and so you can get *something* out of that but it's likely to be different from what you expect; see [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127004/2887218) for more information) we will explore your "another possible solution" which uses a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)-of-[tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) to start with instead of an object type.

---

We need a function like `argsTupleListToTupleType()` which takes an input whose type is an array of key-value pairs (each of which have a keylike type for its first element) and converts it into an array of just values.  We can express this in the type system as

```
declare function argsTupleListToTupleType<T extends any[]>(
  argsTupleList: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: readonly [PropertyKey, T[I]] }]
): T;
```

This function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the output type `T`, and the `argsTupleList` input argument is of a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) on `T`, where each element of `T` has been replaced with a [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) pair with a keylike first member and the element from `T` as the second member.  (Note that `readonly` tuples accept *more* inputs than non-`readonly` tuples, so this is more accommodating.)  Since this is a *homomorphic* mapped type (see [What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59790508/2887218) ) the compiler is able to *infer* `T` from the input value of the mapped type.

Also note that I made the type of `argsTupleList` a `readonly` [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), so `readonly [...XXX]` instead of just `XXX`, which gives the compiler a hint that it should interpret `argsTupleList` as a tuple type where possible, and that it should accept any [`const`-asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) inputs.  Essentially this wrapping just makes the function more accommodating of being called in different ways, without really changing the basic operation.

---

So that's the type system, what about implementation?  Well that's a straightforward `argsTupleList.map(x => x[1])` using [the `map()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).  The TypeScript compiler can't possibly verify that this satisfies the call signature, so we'll need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell it that we've done the checking ourselves and that it shouldn't worry.  (See [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218) for more information):

```
function argsTupleListToTupleType<T extends any[]>(
  argsTupleList: readonly [...{ [I in keyof T]: readonly [PropertyKey, T[I]] }]
): T {
  return argsTupleList.map(x => x[1]) as T;
}
```

---

Let's try it out with your example:

```
type TupleListType = [
  [string, number],
  [string, string],
  [string, boolean],
  [string, string],
];
const argsTupleList: TupleListType = [
  ["prop1", 1],
  ["prop2", "two"],
  ["prop3", true],
  ["prop4", "four"],
]

const tuple = argsTupleListToTupleType(argsTupleList);
// const tuple: [number, string, boolean, string]
console.log(tuple); // [1, "two", true, "four"]
```

Looks good.  Both the type and value of `tuple` are what we expect.  This also works with different inputs:

```
const t2 = argsTupleListToTupleType([
  ["a", 1], ["b", true], ["c", new Date()]
]);
// const t2: [number, boolean, Date]
console.log(t2); // [1, true, Date: "2023-02-28T16:47:56.073Z"] 

const inp = [["x", 0], ["y", null], ["z", undefined]] as const;
const t3 = argsTupleListToTupleType(inp); // const t3: [0, null, undefined]
console.log(t3); // [0, null, undefined]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQEMBOBzAzgFQgAcAbAUwBkFc58lDSz8BPIsgHn1TIA84yoAE1wYozANoBdAHwAKUKgw4CxclRoAuVJjLpBKEs1TiAdGYDexgJKoEaANZlmSMKnyStOvQaPiACphIbJhwzADSTgA0buJWkpKoAL6SoACUWlzmCtpkcBCYaFh4DGrUcCYAtuhEsjyoALzSqDziAIySqRgi+ADcoImgoKFsbqqUZSwj9cbZ4jSYdtjRUBAVAEZkmJKRs-OL0XtQ2Nu7cAtH0WtISOToUCcginNn+6iHxzsgkn0gMCg0SmKY3UcAywImrDIDRmj2MACIiIEiK04dF2p8ngikQAmVGoOFwADuSDhD0xiKCAGY8WcIGQyfCKUQACx4uFgJD5UmfFIgQa-f5wVB5RjQooqRgguglJiQ2TimUg1I-AD0KtQfygAJF5C04hW602BxeF1QVxuuigxvOx1AmtwFpMJCQ2FkOrIytQauMrWiBOJNMwdL9HK5CX5dsFwuxYuUiom9DGkzIsnEszh6Dx6Pha0DdO28JgeKgZEJqAAIuh+LJUryOqr1fahXBsXqDRtMJdrrcrRWq-TI1rHc7XS3Pd62tFaWRopX+Fo4diAAzYykAWhXa+xAA58K0AGwaZkAdg0AFZ9yYl8fKQAtUmoflN2xQIjQ8TiOE8PFLguf5jFhAJAkH+cIAF54tAghkGAdhkII8RdBqgo-M+cCUrGQKSgmMrJrIdhEOOjZRuhepLssQEkNEUEwXBCGDg65BOi6bqUkRxjkagKzAdRQi0SWCGPiAQA)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the minimal repro shared, I wrote up a function which just transforms the structure in a type safe way.

```js
type ObjectType = {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
  prop3: boolean;
  prop4: string;
};

const args: ObjectType = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: "two",
  prop3: true,
  prop4: "four",
};

function someFunc(arg1: number, arg2: string, arg3: boolean, arg4: string) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
}

function composeParameters(obj: ObjectType): Parameters<typeof someFunc> {
  const { prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4 } = obj;
  return [prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4];
}

someFunc(...composeParameters(args));
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXOdOW)

Comment: It has some interesting parts, but it only works for the specific object. The composeParameters function would have to work for other objects as well. I would also be fine to use a Map instead of an object, btw.

Comment: @anarchist912 _what_ other objects? It's not safe (at compile time or at runtime) to just assume that the object's values will come out in a particular order, as it will depend how they were inserted, so to safely spread them into a function you need _something_ to ensure they end up in the right places. `new Map(Object.entries(thing))` doesn't help at runtime, because the map will just retain the same (unknown!) insertion order you're starting with, or at compile time, because it would just be `Map<string, string | boolean | number>`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited my question to ask for a solution to map an array of tuples to a tuple.

Comment: @anarchist912 ...why? Is that _actually_ what you're starting with? It seems increasingly likely that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you have an object and want to get the values out in the right order to pass to a function, this _is_ the right answer.

Comment: yes, it can be what I am starting with. What I am trying to achieve is for writing tests. I want less repetition when passing arguments to a function that takes 12 positional args, and has to be tested multiple times. So I have full control over the initial object – whatever structure it has – but not over the function to be tested. The answer does indeed solve this, but only for one particular use case. I have multiple functions with a lot of args to be passed that need to be tested, so a more generic solution would be nice. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @anarchist912 leaving aside the smell of _"a function that takes 12 positional args"_, why don't you just _start_ with the tuple you want? If you're writing _parameterised tests_, iterate over `Parameters<typeof funcUnderTest>[]`.