# Return the type of an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

How can I type the getFieldsBySlug function so that it returns a typed object

For example:

```
getFieldsBySlug('price')

// return [{ label: "Price, $", slug: "price", type: "checkbox" }]
// not [{ label: string, slug: string, type: string, }]
```

```
const getFieldsBySlug = (...slugs) => {
  return slugs.map((slug) => Fields.find((filed) => filed.slug === slug)) || [];
};

const Fields = [
  {
    label: "Price, $",
    slug: "price",
    type: "checkbox",
  },
  {
    label: "Area",
    slug: "area",
    type: "number",
  },
  {
    label: "Floor",
    slug: "floor",
    type: "grop",
  },
  {
    label: "Finishing",
    slug: "finishing",
    type: "radio",
  },
];
```

I tried to add "as const", but it does not return a specific type, but variants

Comment: The compiler won't be able to infer the tuple-to-tuple mapping so you'll need a type assertion, such as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJVnrW). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I do not understand what you want. The getFieldsBySlug function does not return an object, it returns an array.

Comment: @jcalz, Yes, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer but can you [edit] to show that you’re getting an array out of the function? Or I could do it if you don’t mind

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compiler to keep track of the specific string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the property values of the elements of the `Fields` array, then you'll definitely need something like a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const Fields = [
    {
        label: "Price, $",
        slug: "price",
        type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
        label: "Area",
        slug: "area",
        type: "number",
    },
    {
        label: "Floor",
        slug: "floor",
        type: "grop",
    },
    {
        label: "Finishing",
        slug: "finishing",
        type: "radio",
    },
] as const;
```

And from that we can define some useful types in describing what `getFieldsBySlug()` does:

```
type Field = typeof Fields[number];
type SlugMap = { [F in Field as F["slug"]]: F };
```

The `SlugMap` type evaluates to:

```
/* type SlugMap = {
    price: {
        readonly label: "Price, $";
        readonly slug: "price";
        readonly type: "checkbox";
    };
    area: {
        readonly label: "Area";
        readonly slug: "area";
        readonly type: "number";
    };
    floor: {
        readonly label: "Floor";
        readonly slug: "floor";
        readonly type: "grop";
    };
    finishing: {
        readonly label: "Finishing";
        readonly slug: "finishing";
        readonly type: "radio";
    };
} */
```

so you can think of `getFieldsBySlug` as looking up each element of the `slugs` input as a key in the `SlugMap` type and returning the result.

---

Presumably in your original attempt at `getFieldsBySlug()`, you got an output type that was the equivalent of `Field[]` (where `Field` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of "variants" as you call them).  That type isn't *wrong*, since the output will always be an array of `Field` elements; but it's not specific enough for your purposes.

Well, when you need a function's output type to depend on the type of the input in a programmatic way, you should make it a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.  (If the dependence isn't programmatic then you could make it an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function if you want, but I won't digress about that here.)

That is, it should have the following call signature:

```
declare const getFieldsBySlug: <S extends Array<keyof SlugMap>>(
  ...slugs: S) => { [I in keyof S]: SlugMap[S[I]]; }
```

The `slugs` rest parameter is of generic type `S` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be an array of keys of `SlugMap`. And when you call `getFieldsBySlug()` with a set of specific arguments like `getFieldsBySlug("price", "area")`, `S` will be inferred as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `["price", "area"]`.  And so the output of the function will be a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays); the type `{[ I in keyof S]: SlugMap[S[I]]}` turns a tuple type `S` into another tuple type, where the `I`th element of `S`, of type `S[I]`, is mapped to the corresponding type you get when looking it up in `SlugMap`; that is, `SlugMap[S[I]]`.

So with that call signature you get the following behavior:

```
const result = getFieldsBySlug('price', 'area')
/* 
const result: [{
    readonly label: "Price, $";
    readonly slug: "price";
    readonly type: "checkbox";
}, {
    readonly label: "Area";
    readonly slug: "area";
    readonly type: "number";
}] */
const result2 = getFieldsBySlug('floor', 'finishing', 'floor');
/* const result2: [{
    readonly label: "Floor";
    readonly slug: "floor";
    readonly type: "grop";
}, {
    readonly label: "Finishing";
    readonly slug: "finishing";
    readonly type: "radio";
}, {
    readonly label: "Floor";
    readonly slug: "floor";
    readonly type: "grop";
}] */
const result3 = getFieldsBySlug();
// const result3: []
```

which is what you want.

---

And we're essentially done.  It would be nice if the compiler could verify that the implementation of `getFieldsBySlug()` satisfies the call signature.  But that's beyond it's abilities.  Even if we convince the compiler that `(slug) => Fields.find((filed) => filed.slug === slug)` will convert an input of type `K extends keyof SlugMap` to an output of type `SlugMap[K]`, it can't figure out that the `map()` array method will result in a mapped tuple type.  See [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218) for more information.

That means it's not even worth trying to convince the compiler to follow your implementation logic, and we should instead use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that the output type is what we think it is (after double-checking that it does):

```
const getFieldsBySlug = <S extends Array<keyof SlugMap>>(...slugs: S) => {
    return slugs.map((slug) => Fields.find((filed) => filed.slug === slug)) as
        { [I in keyof S]: SlugMap[S[I]] };
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYgSwKYBsAmEYF4YG0BQMRMA3ocRSgIYBGqAXDAEQAKATgsEgDQwAkTbuQpEIKAK4BzRkwAOHLoOEioAT1lIZwABZJgAaxogAHkooBfIRTIji1OihkBBNkipnbMMVJlVX7q081DRkwcQBbOjYPIktlG097BmY4FBAQaMDbb2lmADM0jJiVdU1mSTYQWWK462VKWmSmRDAECG0EMEliihyZPM62jq6e4mCypjYqNAQQGqEAXRgqTFBIKABufHxx+GR0bBhxkDy91AxcMMikNgWt3YBlCUkAWSpZQ5I8OBhOs4OVvBcEwckwFgtGD9zFsAPQAKiOpRgTykbw+OASRHknDKmJE-jQ4BQqhgSUczHYON4Ai2nhgBKJJL6zGxilpngZYGJiJCzB0ekMJiY7NiIuW-kYeIonO5ZOc-mF9WIMqZz18CrF0rchK5JPGoQiUUVFjFBXSbElSqIKtJjXJzUK0U1yu1jK8avyjuNHNdup5EwqVW9ouUA1a7U6uSlLumbrlKUGEZGzutvu5zKYYaGkeD+LTetKMimMzmYuh+HMMDhMO2MJhMDQemorhga2gMEkSCgiHOEAAQqoUbkADwPGBIYxQJBgDAwFxTVTD-RIVQnZHPNEAPk3AAp8HWiAA6Y85CCMB4ASmwm9IeAAkr8wDBl6vTg8IevUe9cA9cHfwRsMDmNsbawJ23b7BgA5Doco7jpO06zvOVCLi+a5Dluu7Hoep7nleWA3nirhQOIbBPqeh7hO8O47jk+E3j26AQIeYZoDRAwoEgaD0TAHFcThzzYFgOB0VeKxWref6Ps+K7oR+GHfr+-5LOW5b4KB9JIBA4goLAODgYxUGDs8O4AOSskgpm8KZfhuKZF77gi6ngO2rjabpjC4ER+a2g4MiUlw1K5jaGYWcFPn6nyugGEYphbJYpDKDa8ZMC4bjhbGfoZrZ7hijakVMFcRrxUs1bOesmnuVAABMhwGZB-bGVIZlmhkVkwKZWZJpI7WdY69mwgiGluTpNWed5mWynaMipOaGU6umHqZl6eURYW5SVNU8W8BNC0kilLTZsmSU+RmXXDN0q2TQWvKTNMsyKglu1xtNKQrSd13uj4npzVde3+jIgZbRWpU1sNWmjQAzHVXaGY1Q47hesL1uDVWQ55Cz4EAA)