# Approach or workaround to map object literal type to another by function

Tags: typescript

I've seen a few related questions and github issues but will still ask for the specific scenario in case it's not exact same.

If we have an object literal `obj` defined as

```
const obj = {
  num1: 1,
  num2: 2,
} as const;
```

It is currently possible to create and type a function that maps the object values to another type of values, ignoring the issues around Object from entries / entries .. etc.

```
const mapObj = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, R>(
  obj: T,
  mapFn: (v: T[keyof T]) => R
): { [K in keyof T]: R } => ({} as any);
```

Calling the function gives pretty good results.

```
const mapped = mapObj(obj, (v) => `${v}`);
const mappedConst = mapObj(obj, (v) => `${v}` as const);
```

returns

```
{
  readonly num1: string;
  readonly num2: string;
}
```

and

```
{
    readonly num1: "1" | "2";
    readonly num2: "1" | "2";
}
```

respectively, depending on the passed function.

I'd like to know if there is some approach that can allow the exact value types to be returned. key `num1` should be `"1"` and `num2` `"2"`.

```
const mapObjExact = <T extends Record<string, unknown>, F extends <K extends keyof T>(k:K, v: T[K]) => unknown>(
  obj: T,
  mapFn: F
): { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<F> } => ({} as any);
```

I don't think there's any way to provide additional information to `ReturnType` as to which type of argument it would be called with so this approach I think won't work. But maybe there's a different way to structure the function.

I thought this may something to do with higher kinded types etc ... On the other hand something like this for single value works.

```
const apply=<const T extends unknown,const R>(v:T,fn:(v:T)=>R):R=>fn(v)

const v1 = apply(2,(n)=>`${n}`) //"2"
```

But this is directly on one argument so guess easier for typescript to determine the type.

I'd guess its probably not possible, but wondering if with any of the newer typescript features like the const generic assertion, or some other approach, it is possible to get this to work.

Comment: yes that answers it, thanks

Comment: That's cool, think it could be worth it in some cases. And when it can be used with mapped types to create the type it's not much more work. Yea would be nice to have that also in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to possibly work, TypeScript would need to look at the function `` const f = v => `${v}` `` and infer it as having different output types for different input types. That means it would either need to be seen as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function (of a type like `` <T extends number>(v: T) => `${T}` ``) or an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) (of a type like `{ (v: 1): "1"; (v: 2): "2"; }`). And it needs to do so purely at the type level, without you actually directly *calling* it like `f(1)` or `f(2)`.

But unfortunately TypeScript mostly lacks the ability to manipulate generic or overload types directly at the type level.  In order to do that TypeScript would need *higher kinded types*, possibly of the sort requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213#issuecomment-1107908830).  Specifically here I'd say you would need true *call types*, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179).
A call type would answer the question "for a function `f` of type `F`, and an argument array `a` of type `A`, what is the type of `f(...a)`?"  Maybe we could call that `Call<F, A>` or even `F(...A)`, but it doesn't exist in the language for now.

```
// NOT VALID TYPESCRIPT: DO NOT TRY THISL
const f = <T extends number>(v: T) => `${v}` as const;
type FReturn<T extends number> = Call<F, [T]>;
// type FReturn<T extends number> = `${T}`
```

Right now all you can do is take a function type `F` and ask for its return type via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) like [`ReturnType<F>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).  That necessarily this necessarily turns the input function type `F` into a non-generic non-overloaded function type, by erasing any generic type parameters and by using only the last call signature.  So you'll get a single return type that doesn't depend on the input argument list at all.  This is insufficient for your purposes:

```
const f = <T extends number>(v: T) => `${v}` as const;
type FReturn<T extends number> = ReturnType<typeof f>; 
// type FReturn<T extends number> = `${number}`
```

So there's no hope of getting this to work, at least not with type inference.

---

The closest I can imagine doing is to let you manually specify the input type `T` and output type `U` of `mapObject`, and then have the compiler *compute* an appropriate overloaded function type (by representing overloads as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of function types, which we can get via a contravariance trick similar to how [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218) works):

```
type KeyMapper<T extends object, U extends Record<keyof T, any>> =
    { [K in keyof T]: (x: (x: T[K]) => U[K]) => void } extends
    Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never;

type KeyMapped = KeyMapper<{ num1: 1, num2: 2 }, { num1: "1", num2: "2" }>;
// type KeyMapped = ((x: 1) => "1") & ((x: 2) => "2")
```

Then `mapObject()` could be written like this:

```
function mapObject<T extends object, U extends Record<keyof T, any>>(
    t: T, map: KeyMapper<T, U>): U {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(t).map(
        ([k, v]) => [k, (map as any)(v)])) as any
}
```

And you could call it, although there's no way for the compiler to infer an overloaded type from a function body.  Instead we're forced to manually specify type arguments *and* make the actual function generic so that the compiler has some chance of type checking it:

```
const obj = { num1: 1, num2: 2 } as const;
const f = <T extends number>(v: T) => `${v}` as const;
    
const mappedConst = mapObject<
    typeof obj, { num1: "1", num2: "2" }
>(obj, f); // okay
```

This type checks.  The compiler is able to at least verify that `` <T extends number>(v: T) => `${T}` `` is assignable `((x: 1) => "1") & ((x: 2) => "2")` even though it can't *infer* the latter type from the former.

So there you go, the closest I can imagine getting without a change to the language requires a lot more hardcoding of types than one would like, but at least it's *something*.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIFkCGZICcA8AVKEAewEAdgCYDOUA9gEYBWEAxsADRQCquBx5UASo5TQkMAa3iUAZlCyskREAD4FUALwAoKJqgBvKAG0YUAJZEoYkJOkBdAFxQAFHjuO7WA1YCUq5W3deVygBulEYkUAC+nISkZBpa-AyCwmTAaCYA5qwuxkQSEGhQAJL+QSEkygD8RVB2RBCB+QDcamoSAK5ETEaUpgC2KADydIzA2FHcFDT0TKwc+NE8CUmi4lIyUHKKCvZxmsCurP1gdnCIKOjYswoedhzau1BoEMBtaKZD08AAdBJolL0AUSIqSMEDI9g+Iy+xBBYPswA8XyOOy0qIcehErECnm8+kxDiOGwomw89kCHk8XiQxPkanCLVAkFg8GQqAgYRUzLObMwuiIbV6AEY7ILWPzegAmOwSiKsPkC4VQABEgqVYoFUuVEqVEQUzQA9PqoIzoKdWZAOQ5soKSsrVV4AGRWpxQCW2pXajwtRJEFJUOiqHRQcWK0XBjXSiJEqA+lLNWPAKBSTljeYTcO9aj5baBVy2gAGABJtIFwvnownmmoTVAAMJIAA2DYAYoH+C83lhwBAMCbLBI9WpDcbu3XGy3A0XtOKs2gy96en6jhba4vE5yjpCmBgHn2pFM5RnFSq1RnNR6dfTtgekx5GlBh5QREgQAvfZQGxAvg3KOl7Mv2VXX0ESAA)

Comment: Nice, I think despite having to provide the type explicitly this is still very useful to provide type safety for cases where you have complex but structured data to transform.

Comment: I guess the same approach using intersection of functions would also work for tuples for example in in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091118/mapping-tuple-typed-value-to-different-tuple-typed-value-without-casts) you mentioned before?

Comment: Maybe, if anyone wanted to specify the type arguments the same way

Comment: [Doesn't look great](https://tsplay.dev/N9Vb3m), at least not when the call to `map()` is itself generic.  When its non-generic then I guess it works, but it's so tedious that it doesn't feel more appealing then just doing it manually (e.g., `[f(a[0]), f(a[1]), f(a[2])] as const` or something)

Comment: yea that's fair. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that for a generic case,
but for any single case you may use `ReturnType<typeof fn<GenericArg>>`
to get the return type of a function with manually provided generic args

```
const obj = {
    num1: 1,
    num2: 2,
} as const;

type In = string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined;

function str<T extends In>(v: T): `${T}` { return `${v}` }

function omap<O extends Record<string, In>, V>(o: O, fn: (v: O[keyof O]) => V): { [K in keyof O]: V } {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [k, fn(v as any)])
    ) as any
}

let A = omap(obj, str);
//  ^?
console.log(A)
// let A: {
//     readonly num1: "1" | "2";
//     readonly num2: "1" | "2";
// }

function omap_str<O extends Record<string, In>>(
    o: O
): {[K in keyof O]: ReturnType<typeof str<O[K]>>} {
    //                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // you may use typeof function as a generic
    return omap(o, str) as any;
}

let B = omap_str(obj);
//  ^?
console.log(B)
// let B: {
//     readonly num1: "1";
//     readonly num2: "2";
// }
```

Comment: Relevant docs: this approach uses [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions). If you could use these purely at the type level then this could almost be a way to implement exactly what the question asked... [but you can't](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058192563) unfortunately.