I need help strongly typing typescript object entries
I'm trying to make my own static class that adds some extra typings to Object.entries and Object.fromEntries. I feel I'm halfway there but am running into issues when getting it to implicitly detect values passed into array helper methods like .map().
Below is my Typescript Utility Class for Type Safety:
type TransformEntry<Entry, Val> = Entry extends [infer K, infer _V] ? [K, Extract<Val, Val>] : never;

export class Obj {
  // ---- Type Helpers for Object ----
  static entries<T extends object>(obj: T): { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][] {
    return Object.entries(obj) as { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][];
  }
  static fromEntries<T extends ([string, unknown])[]>(entries: T) {
    return Object.fromEntries(entries) as { [K in T[number][0]]: Extract<T[number], [K, unknown]>[1] };
  }

  // ---- Custom Methods ----
  static updateEntryVal = <
    Entry extends [string, unknown],
    NewValue,
  >([key]: Entry, val: NewValue) => [key, val] as TransformEntry<Entry, NewValue>;
}


I partially have this working with .map() function with certain issues
I have created Obj.updateEntryVal() to better implicitly type the return value of .map() function
I am looking for an implicit solution that just detects any return value passed in to .map()
I want to avoid having to make a custom interface somwhere else in the code since it should rely on being implicit

Below is the type test:
const fruit = {
  fruitName: 'apple' as const,
  description: 'A sweet red fruit',
  weight: 175,
  isFresh: true,
};

// ✅ Works fine without applying .map() function
const entries = Obj.entries(fruit);
const newObj = Obj.fromEntries(entries);
// Working ✅
const fruitName = newObj.fruitName; // "apple" as const
const description = newObj.description; // string
const weight = newObj.weight; // number
const isFresh = newObj.isFresh; // boolean

// ✅ Example 1 (Working) - Update entry with a new value as a number
const example1 = Obj.entries(fruit).map((entry) =>
  Obj.updateEntryVal(entry, 123)
);
const result1 = Obj.fromEntries(example1);
const fruitName1 = result1.fruitName; // working: number
const fruitDescription1 = result1.description; // working: number
const fruitWeight1 = result1.weight; // working: number
const fruitIsFresh1 = result1.isFresh; // working: number

// ❎ Example 2 (Broken) - Retain original value
const example2 = Obj.entries(fruit).map((entry) =>
  Obj.updateEntryVal(entry, entry[1])
);
const result2 = Obj.fromEntries(example2);
const fruitName2 = result2.fruitName;
// - desired: 'apple' as const
// - result: string | number | boolean
const fruitDescription2 = result2.description;
// - desired: string
// - result: string | number | boolean
const fruitWeight2 = result2.weight;
// - desired: number
// - result: string | number | boolean
const fruitIsFresh2 = result2.isFresh;
// - desired: boolean
// - result: string | number | boolean

// ❎ Example 3 (Broken) - Transform value with a function
const example3 = Obj.entries(fruit).map((entry) =>
  Obj.updateEntryVal(entry, () => entry[1])
);
const result3 = Obj.fromEntries(example3);
const fruitName3 = result3.fruitName; 
// - desired: () => 'apple' as const
// - result: () => string | number | boolean
const fruitDescription3 = result3.description;
// - desired: () => string
// - result: () => string | number | boolean
const fruitWeight3 = result3.weight;
// - desired: () => number
// - result: () => string | number | boolean
const fruitIsFresh3 = result3.isFresh;
// - desired: () => boolean
// - result: () => string | number | boolean

// ❎ Example 4 (Broken) - Wrap value in an object
const example4 = Obj.entries(fruit).map((entry) =>
  Obj.updateEntryVal(entry, { test: entry[1] })
);
const result4 = Obj.fromEntries(example4);
const fruitName4 = result4.fruitName;
// - desired: { test: 'apple' as const }
// - result: { test: string | number | boolean }
const fruitDescription4 = result4.description;
// - desired: { test: string }
// - result: { test: string | number | boolean }
const fruitWeight4 = result4.weight;
// - desired: { test: number }
// - result: { test: string | number | boolean }
const fruitIsFresh4 = result4.isFresh;
// - desired: { test: boolean }
// - result: { test: string | number | boolean }

I think the issue is with <Val> and being able to infer it. If <Val> comes as a Union Type how do we infer/extract it to match infer K? Example2 also seems to be the same union as infer _V
// Note: The union matching to create a working Object.fromEntries() works if we incorrectly use infer _V.
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Context:
// Entry: ["fruitName", "apple"] | ["description", string] | ["weight", number] | ["isFresh", boolean]
  // infer K: "fruitName" | "description" | "weight" | "isFresh"
  // infer _V: "apple" | string | number | boolean
// Val: 
  // - Example 1: 123 - number
  // - Example 2: entry[1] - "apple" | string | number | boolean - Same union as infer _V but does not key match with infer K
  // - Example 3: () => entry[1] - () => string | number | boolean
  // - Example 4: { test: entry[1] } - { test: string | number | boolean }
type TransformEntry<Entry, Val> = Entry extends [infer K, infer _V] ? [K, Extract<Val, Val>] : never;


For additional reference this is my tsconfig.json environment
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}


What's fruit? We need a [mre] we can copy and paste into our IDEs to get working on this.

Thanks for catching that. I had added the fruit const variable in now.

It looks like you expect your callback functions to be automagically generic without annotations; this isn't possible, you need to annotate them as such. But then it also looks like you expect TS to be able to express higher kinded types or call types for the map function, and TS just cannot do that at all.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/76940974/2887218, which this question effectively duplicates.

I guess I didn't write this so as to garner a reply, let me rephrase: do you agree that the issue is essentially higher kinded types or call types as described in the other question and answer? That approach looks like this playground link for your example, and it's just... it's really more than TS can handle in an ergonomic way. Anyway, if you agree, let me know and I'll likely close this as a duplicate of that; if not, please [edit] to clarify the difference.
