# Typescript generics with selectors and mapper

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I want to write a generic selector and mapper method.

```
interface State {
    user: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }
}

const selectName = (state: State) => state.user.name;
const selectAge = (state: State) => state.user.age;

const state: State = { user: { name: 'John Doe', age: 38 } };
```

Now I want a generic method in TypeScript which will give me the following without using any or object.

```
const selector = buildSelector(selectName, selectAge, (name, age) => `${name} - ${age}`);
```

1. buildSelector can get `...args` of selectors with the signature (state: State) => can return anything.
2. And the last parameter will be a mapper function which will automatically know the types it will receive

Comment: Fixed the typos and reformatted.

Comment: Are you looking for the call signature typing or the implementation?  If it's the typing then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1avOw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ok you're almost there. What I need is `buildSelector` should execute the callback on invocation and return the result back. If that's done then I will give your answer +1. :)

Comment: So you care about the implementation also?  Then it looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKKDgW). I hope it's okay that the implementation uses type assertions and `any` since the compiler cannot possibly follow the sort of reasoning required with splitting the array at the end and mapping functions with dependent types.  Let me know if that suffices or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. You can post the answer and I will mark it as the correct one. :+1

Comment: Done.  Ugh it always takes one minute to write the code and one hour to explain it

Comment: @jcalz I have another one for you. It is almost the same just the signature is different. I tried a bit but could not wrap my head around it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77061545/typescript-generics-for-array-of-selector-to-mapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd write `buildSelector()`:

```
function buildSelector<T extends any[], U>(...args: [
  ...selectors: { [I in keyof T]: (state: State) => T[I] },
  callback: (...args: T) => U
]): (state: State) => U {
  const selectors = args.slice(0, -1) as ((state: State) => any)[];
  const callback = args.at(-1) as (...args: any) => U;
  return (state) => callback(...selectors.map(f => f(state)))
}
```

The call signature is fairly complicated, mostly because we need to represent that we expect to receive an arbitrary number of selectors *followed by* a single callback function.  That's like using a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and then putting an extra parameter after it.  But JavaScript only supports putting the rest parameter at the *end* of the parameter list.  So conceptually the function would look like

```
// not valid TS nor valid JS, do not use:
function buildSelector<T extends any[], U>(
  ...selectors: { [I in keyof T]: (state: State) => T[I] },
  callback: (...args: T) => U
): (state: State) => U {
  return (state) => callback(...selectors.map(f => f(state)))
}
```

Let's look at that hypothetical version first and then talk about the real-world one.  The function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of arguments to the `callback`, as well as the tuple of *return types* of the `selectors` array.  The type of `selectors` is therefore a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `T`, so that the `I`th element of `selectors` is of type `(state: State) => T[I]`, a `State`-accepting function that returns the `I`th element of `T`.  And `buildSelector` is also generic in `U`, the return type of `callback`.

The hypothetical implementation is also fairly straightforward: it's a function that accepts `state` and calls the `callback` on a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ped version of `selectors`, where each element of `selectors` is called with `state` as the argument.  Note that the compiler can't possibly follow the logic involved when using `map()` on a tuple, see [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218).  So in the real-world version the implementation will require some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which aren't necessary in our hypothetical world where leading rest elements are accepted in JavaScript.

---

Okay now back to the real world:

```
function buildSelector<T extends any[], U>(...args: [
  ...selectors: { [I in keyof T]: (state: State) => T[I] },
  callback: (...args: T) => U
]): (state: State) => U {
  const selectors = args.slice(0, -1) as ((state: State) => any)[];
  const callback = args.at(-1) as (...args: any) => U;
  return (state) => callback(...selectors.map(f => f(state)))
}
```

Since the argument list can be of variable length, with the variable part at the beginning, we have no choice but to give the function a single `args` rest parameter right at beginning.  And while there's no support for a leading rest parameter in JavaScript, we're lucky that there *is* support for a [leading rest tuple element](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) in TypeScript.  So the type of `args` is a variadic tuple with a leading rest `selectors` element and a final `callback` element.  The types of those are the same as before.

Inside the function implementation, we need to break `args` into `selectors` and `callback`.  We can't do that with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) like `const [...selectors, callback] = args` because JavaScript doesn't support leading rest elements there either.  So we use array methods like [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`at()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at).  You can do it however you want, of course.

And I'm using assertions and [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to give `selectors` and `callback` loose enough types that the compiler will not complain about `return (state) => callback(...selectors.map(f => f(state)))`.  As mentioned before, we need them because the compiler can't understand that `selectors.map(f => f(state))` will return a value of type `T`.  But we also need them because the compiler can't understand that `at(-1)` will produce the final callback function type (and not a selector type) and `slice(0, -1)` will produce the tuple of selector types (and not the final callback type).  That is, slicing and splitting tuple-typed arrays doesn't produce tuple types. There was a feature request to support strong typing for negative indices with `at` at [microsoft/TypeScript#47660](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47660), but it was declined as being too complex.  So the best you can do here is to assert that the implementation is correct and give up on the compiler verifying much.

---

Okay, that's the explanation. Let's see if it works:

```
const selector = buildSelector(
  selectName, selectAge, (name, age) => `${name} - ${age}`
);

const x = selector(state);
// const x: string
console.log(x) // "John Doe - 38"
```

Looks good!  The compiler [contextually infers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the `name` and `age` parameter types of the final callback to be `string` and `number`, respectively.  And it also understands that `selector` is of type `(state: State)=>string` since the callback return type is `string`.  And you can see that the implementation also works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.2.2#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-UEMJ0tAYJo-n8Pgmn0VwICaRJaQAAwAEmwaDul7ZBkMScR4LMZI6y8c4gjA51R1wgZ+lnd9ziYFh2DfYhZFUexlFkNh9HOCx+gogAiMpKhqOpkHQjpuOQIA)