# Typescript generics for array of selector to mapper

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
interface State {
    user: {
        name: string;
        age: number;
    }
}

const selection = (state: State) => [state.user.name, state.user.age] as const;
const state: State = { user: { name: 'John Doe', age: 38 } };
```

What I want is enricher to be a generic method which can take a store object, an array of selectors and the mapper will automatically the intellisense of the possible properties.

I tried the generics below but getting stuck with the selectors and mappers part.

```
const enricher = <T extends any[], U>(
  state: State,
  selectors: (state: State) => T,
  mapper: (...args: T) => U): U => {
  // ?
}

const result = enricher(state, selection, (name, age) => `${firstName} - ${age}`);
console.log(result); // "John Doe - 38"
```

Comment: If you do that, you have to inline the arrow functions into the function call. Otherwise, you'd have to add in the types yourself and that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. Updated and formatted.

Comment: This works @jcalz
Thank you. +1 for you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write `enricher()`:

```
function enricher<T extends any[], U>(state: State,
  selectors: (state: State) => readonly [...T],
  mapper: (...args: T) => U
) {
  return mapper(...selectors(state))
}
```

This is fairly straightforward: the function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the arraylike return type of `selectors`, and `U`, the return type of `mapper`.  The only wrinkle is giving `selectors` the return type of `readonly [...T]` instead of `T`, allowing the return type to be the wider [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) version of it (by wrapping in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) `[...`+`]`).  It makes the function more versatile and since the implementation doesn't modify the contents of the value returned from `selectors`, it shouldn't hurt anything.

And the implementation is really just `mapper(...selectors(state))`, which is [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the result of `selectors(state)` into the arguments list for `mapper`.

Let's test it out:

```
const state: State = { user: { name: 'John Doe', age: 38 } };
const selection = (state: State) => [state.user.name, state.user.age] as const;     
const result = enricher(state, selection, (name, age) => `${name} - ${age}`);
// const result: string
console.log(result) // "John Doe - 38"
```

Looks good.  The compiler [contextually infers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the types of the `name` and `age` callback parameters, and the returned `result` is a `string` of the expected form.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpZBvAUM5AVwGdoAuHfA5EOAWwguLClAHMBuKguNxmwnQBG0LgQC+uSbhiEQCMMAD2IZBBCsEAC2gAeACpqAHpBAATYsjggAngG0AugBpkAVQB8ACmaZ+6X05UpAA2EApKUMQU3hiQFP6QAJTIALzuyFAQcGYqwTbIdgB0xfrOVHRwAA6V5MiexYVwUGxRyPrJaW64yXgEmWCEUKoV1dD1xSFhYBHEMb6JiVK4ywgqzMg+cWixKCk4RKRQFNg09PwA5ABSSlqqACJKEOcuvPwAzAAcyOLfXKsg60mCmUqj2cy2CQgHXSdk2EEKJGghVoDBccIRh0afAcVks-2YHGQAHoichdABacm45D4sDIACE9JWazpmWIhGCdL26k0Oig4IgaIgoWBKhcnhRgqsfGhyAABgASbCSn5UpWvcRyxJcEk0lkZCDszlMFjsXD4pShQrBJRsTxsjlgZK6gBE11uyAeKCpnxdyGWuCAA)