# How to get TS to do type inference with recursive discriminated unions?

Tags: typescript, recursion, discriminated-union

What is a mechanism I can use in TS to have TS do type inference with recursive discriminated unions?

Given the example below:

```
interface Circle {
    type: 'circle';
    radius: 3;
}

interface Square {
    type: 'square';
    sides: 4;
}

interface Bag {
    type: 'bag';
    color: 'green';
    children: AnyItem[];
}

type AnyItem = Circle | Square | Bag;

interface CircleConstructorParams {
    type: 'circle';
}

interface SquareConstructorParams {
    type: 'square';
}

interface BagConstructorParams {
    type: 'bag';
    children: AnyConstructorParams[];
}

type AnyConstructorParams = CircleConstructorParams | SquareConstructorParams | BagConstructorParams;

function getItem(itemConstructorParams: AnyConstructorParams) {
    if (itemConstructorParams.type === 'circle') {
        const circle: Circle = {
            type: 'circle',
            radius: 3,
        };
        return circle;
    } else if (itemConstructorParams.type === 'square') {
        const square: Square = {
            type: 'square',
            sides: 4,
        };
        return square;
    } else if (itemConstructorParams.type === 'bag') {
        const bag: Bag = {
            type: 'bag',
            color: 'green',
            children: itemConstructorParams.children.map(child => {
                return getItem(child);
            })
        };
        return bag;
    }
    throw new Error('Invalid');
}

const circle = getItem({ type: 'circle' });
console.log(circle.radius);

const square = getItem({ type: 'square' });
console.log(square.sides);

const nested = getItem({
    type: 'bag',
    children: [
        { type: 'square', },
        { type: 'circle', },
        {
            type: 'bag',
            children: [
                { type: 'square' },
                { type: 'circle' },
            ]
        },
    ],
});
console.log(nested.children[2].children[1].radius);
```

I receive the following errors:

```
Property 'radius' does not exist on type 'Circle | Square | Bag'.
  Property 'radius' does not exist on type 'Square'.
Property 'sides' does not exist on type 'Circle | Square | Bag'.
  Property 'sides' does not exist on type 'Circle'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Circle | Square | Bag'.
  Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Circle'.
```

Given that I've used literal members, type guards and typed returned objects, I'd expect TS to be able to infer the type of each nested "Item", from each nested "Item constructor".

What is the reason for TS being unable to infer types when used in this way, and what is the correct way to do this, whilst avoiding doing the following:

`console.log((((nested as Bag).children[2] as Bag).children[1] as Circle).radius);`

Comment: TS doesn't infer generic function types, so `getItem()` returns `Circle | Square | Bag`. It doesn't relate the input type to the output type, even if this weren't recursive.  If this were not recursive I'd show how to refactor to a generic function to do this with compiler-verified type safety, but you're expecting the compiler to understand that `map()` converts a tuple of inputs into a corresponding tuple of outputs, and that just doesn't happen, as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218.  I can write something that works, but you'll need type assertions. Would that suffice?

Comment: Like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WKrggm), but the overload hides the fact that the compiler has no idea how to verify the implementation correctness.  Still, it gives you what you want from the caller side.  Let me know how you want to proceed.