# Typescript type predicate mapped through to tuple elements

Tags: typescript, types, predicate

Consider a union of two types with a type predicate

```ts
type Maybe<T> = T | Error
function isValid<T>(value: Maybe<T>): value is T {
  return !(value instanceof Error)
}
```

Lets have code with several computed `Maybe` values and we want a type predicate which summarily checks all of them to *not* be an `Error`:

```ts
const a: Maybe<string> = ... // some function returning Maybe<string>
const b: Maybe<number> = ...
...

if (![a, b, /*and more*/].every(isValid)) {
  return;
}
const realA: string = a;
//Type 'Maybe<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
//  Type 'Error' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygFEAnUge1ICgAzAVwDsBjYASwsajYGcA1OABs2AE3QYAFADch9CAC5YCZOICUimYLnceeKAG9qUKKQjB6pLgEJps6G0Y9gcFhAq0S5KquoBfagEMLOycULQS6lBSFKIGRlDMnE5QjBQA7jgpEBkAInDAEBEAdADmZmhsALaFqgDc8YmOwFBwivBIqE6kDiVYuKkZWACMUAD8UADkcBNQiozZnpSk9caNyYhtyqiM9JXIpH1QQysJSc3Mmx0oFIgAVhCsh-pQAB6KQ761UAHGbB4SVgA2nAADRQRBg5gAXSKECkEFIIAkvAEwhEqlUcWMxlM5ksJ38qzOUBE+TgmWBYMQMNobEEBVIyP4QlEPiJTRMECEAEFFF0epk4PV-EA)

Despite the `every(isValid)` the compiler cannot derive that none of `a`, `b`,... is a `Maybe` any more.

Of course I could write

```ts
if (!isValid(a) && !isValid(b) && ...) {
  return;
}
```

to help the compiler along. But I have 5 to 10 `a`s and `b`s and am in general curious if there is a solution. If have tried

```ts
const data = [a, b].filter(isValid)
```

but this creates a mishmash array type like `(string | number)[]`, so that a `data[0]` is still not decisively a `string`.

So neither `every` nor `filter` do the trick of allowing the compiler to strip the `Maybe` afterwards, but I wonder if there is a summarily, "loopy" way which avoids a cumbersome `if(!isValid(a)...` sequence.

Comment: There are several problems. 1: type guard functions narrow arguments, not their contents; so `allValid([a, b, c])` narrows an anonymous array literal and thus has no visible effect. You could write `const t = [a, b, c] as const; if (allValid(t)) { }` and narrow `t`, but then you'd have to write `t[0]` etc to see the effects. 2: you'd need a hardcoded `allValid(t)` function; you couldn't have `all(isValid, t)` because that would require all's call signature be written as a *higher kinded type* which TS doesn't support; there's no way to talk about what `isValid` does generically. (cont'd)

Comment: (see prev comment) So the best you can get here is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WYyovW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write this up as a full answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Great, yes. This very useful. (And sorry for the late reply.)

Comment: I think I figured out how to do the same with an object `const values = { a: Maybe<...> = ..., b: Maybe<...> = .. }` to get out an object with the `Maybe`s stripped, which then allows to use `values.a` instead of `tup[0]` etc. `<T extends Record<string, Maybe<unknown>>` instead of the `T extends any[]` seems to suffice. You may find it interesting to include this in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to use a custom type guard function to narrow just the contents or members of a value.

Custom type guard functions, which return a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)
of the form `arg is Type` or `this is Type`, only narrow the apparent type of the specific argument corresponding to `arg` or the object corresponding to `this`.  Any effects of narrowing would only be seen through subsequent accesses of the identical value.  Custom type guard functions do not separately affect the apparent types of values which were assigned to *members* of `arg` or `this`.  For example:

```
declare function g(
  x: { a: RegExp | Date }
): x is { a: Date };
const a = Math.random()<0.5 ? new Date() : new RegExp("")
//    ^? const a: RegExp | Date
const x = { a };
//    ^? const x: { a:RegExp | Date; }
if (g(x)) {
  x.a;
  //^? (property) a: Date
  a;
//^? const a: RegExp | Date
}
```

In the above, calling `g(x)` has the effect of narrowing the apparent type of `x` to `{a: Date}`, and therefore narrowing the apparent type of `x.a` to `Date`.  But `a`, a reference to the same value as `x.a`, has *not* been narrowed.

That means it is essentially useless to use a custom type guard function on an anonymous [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) or an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals):

```
if (g({ a })) {
  a;
  //^? const a: RegExp | Date
  ({ a }).a
  //      ^? (property) a: RegExp | Date
}
```

The object literal `{ a }` cannot be accessed again; it's anonymous.  Writing `{ a }` a second time just gives us a new object.  And we know that `a` itself doesn't get narrowed.  So we're stuck.

There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#46184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46184) asking for support to narrow object contents (specifically the destructured variables of object literals; presumably for array literals as well), but for now it's not part of the language.

--

You were trying to narrow an array literal `[a, b, ⋯]` with the [type guard call signature for the `every()` method](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/14da4889691e310d479327072b05544f3c1ec555/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1414), but as we have just seen, this wouldn't have any effect:

```
const now = new Date().getTime();
const a: Maybe<string> = now > 1 ? 'a' : new Error;
const b: Maybe<number> = now > 1 ? 1 : new Error;
const c: Maybe<null> = now > 1 ? null : new Error;
if ([a, b, c].every(isValid)) {
  a.toUpperCase(); // error, Maybe<string> 
}
```

Okay, well, what if we assign the array literal to a variable first and access the members through indices later? That fixes the problem with being anonymous:

```
const arr = [a, b, c];
// const arr: (string | number | Error | null)[]
if (arr.every(isValid)) {
  const newA = arr[0]; // const newA: string | number | null
}
```

So, we get narrowing, hooray.  Kind of.  Unfortunately the array `arr` is of type `Maybe<string | number | null>[]`.  So even though we've narrowed `arr[0]` to `string | number | null`, we've completely lost track of the *order* of the inputs.  That brings us to our next problem:

---

To keep track of the order of `arr`'s elements, we'd need it to have a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) instead.  And `every` doesn't act as an element-wise type guard on tuples:

```
const tup = [a, b, c] as const;
// const tup: readonly [Maybe<string>, Maybe<number>, Maybe<null>]
if (tup.every(isValid)) {
  tup // const tup: readonly [Maybe<string>, Maybe<number>, Maybe<null>] 
}
```

And there's no way to fix that. TypeScript currently lacks the expressiveness necessary to describe how to perform element-wise type guards on tuples.  It would require some way of talking about an *arbitrary* generic type `F` at the type level, maybe like:

```
// NOT VALID TS, DO NOT TRY THIS
function every<T extends any[], F extends ‍♂️>(
  arr: T, cb: <U extends T[number]>(v: U, i: number, a: T) => value is F<U>
): {[I in keyof T]: F<T[I]>}
```

But you can't do that. `F` is a generic type parameter that behaves like a specific type; you can't instantiate it with its own type arguments like `F<U>` or `F<T[I]>`.  There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) but it's not part of the language.  There are various ways to try to simulate/encode such types, but they are not user-friendly enough to suggest here.

See [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218) for more details about a similar issue.

So we'll have to give up on using some kind of *general* type guard mapper that takes `isValid` as an input, and just go ahead and hardcode `isValid()` in there.

---

If we want to use an array, we can write

```
function isEveryElementValid<T extends readonly any[]>(
  values: { [K in keyof T]: Maybe<T[K]> }): values is T {
  return values.every(isValid);
}
```

and then use it like

```
if (isEveryElementValid(tup)) {
  const realA = tup[0]; // const realA: string
  const realB = tup[1]; // const realB: number
  const realC = tup[2]; // const realC: null
}
```

Or if we want to use an object, we can write

```
function isEveryPropertyValid<T extends object>(
  values: { [K in keyof T]: Maybe<T[K]> }): values is T {
  return Object.values(values).every(isValid);
}
```

and then use it like

```
const o = {a,b,c};
if (isEveryPropertyValid(o)) {
  const realA = o.a; // string
  const realB = o.b; // number
  const realC = o.c; // null
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygFEAnUge1ICgAzAVwDsBjYASwsajYGcA1OABs2AE3QYAFADch9CAC5YCZOICUimYLnceeKAG9qUKKQjB6pLgEJps6G0Y9gcFhAq0S5KquoBfagEiEMyCcKZQDCzsnFAA5hJGUAAeivpQcIoAShCxxElghFAAInDA0P7qyToG6YolZVC+ANzUzJxO6ThKwAAWAHSkLiIUALYSqlAoUAAMfQCsUAD8UIwQAO7FpRDjUIqrG9m5+RIARCc+APQXxsYAesttjsC1UId5BUT1EK3tz0ldaTgjRaVxuUHuUEeHRSNQyb3yhS+TUa1DYHgk8SSqgmhmMST6cBaxiuEIkYEokFIoAmGU2ZUShMSJIevxe8I+dO+-lR6PigMa2IMiQk-N8qgJTOuYPByzJFIgVJANKyOXeiK2DKJUGZkNZtPZ6vp3IC1CCITC0ChzzCpEU8CQqCcpAcsQwAG0ALotNFQCQ2voQKQKkASXgCYQiQW49LkLXMq0x21QJ0uz0M8h9EZwMASf7YLD44AUACqYEpAGE4DxttjkaCKABrBB+AI+iRuvqdm0egNB0ghsNCURR9OkOMXe4Jm125SO4DOxiutPGf1ZnN5gt9IulitVmuqOvXBWUGjGyKsDhcXjEPsgYiCCAjCCMYDh0ToKAQJJlRgiXSmOBhkYQQQHSRgQE9SREk0OQeFSKA3QAaW4LgGwgEB3DwD0ZwddAkI9LAxQ0OxdF4PRo1McxLCgGCIB4Xtg1Dfgh0jFozyYC8YmvW8AAV5UVN8xHwL8fz-KAKEQAArYJgCg4xaLgmokJQqA0Iwjw0GwpRcLQfDCMqBTqnwCizAsLgAHkpJkvoFNsLQ6PFQNGMHCMDxbOgOOiLhaHGDQKFEIVjATRgKA2XB9k5cY+liMw0DYJ9xi1KccJUFNFywcLQqgLAAEYligAByOACt2FZ1k8E8ktZRAUtQRh6BGZBSAylYsty-K8r2cqyEqxIE2YWqUHqwRBBakKNna5ZhsEUqIp6qgWkSNs3TgAAaKBEHW5geyc-smMEkcwTgLcSzLBVK2rRLtSPLxSHW+1UvnF0sEAXg3ACI9xJuSCvVyC6Fb1s2yEvUlXUnkTRQJDS2JCnqxqFUKebSBh+gRtUZduHRf1doHZjXJxRJvrB-YAEEuhtN1pi9a7QY6EnFCh5G4aRohpqgT6TUJjpzAKXB-o2raPXSXQrXHGnnm5xQAKAkCEIeucF1de7ZyGhqmowJXcOmjAPSW9FuYYvaXOHfGwW56mEwlkwIEAzgZbdOWUCh9XtJUWG1Y112UdGwWXsAfD32d131uODe9H2fV8WIkbnDpuBMAMEUncG5imqdBOPrYT+mnsXAmxatoQACEumTnLU+udPC72VWFVzivBHLYv6DAN0ACYy7z+Pyyrkb2c554KABNbNuYZpA6Ym9gz4ihKVAQSJAoGO+-zhOugoAlD2TbPYlr1l46L3A18QDe3ZrsE64bg++mYY+vYDlsgA)