# Mapping function to return the corresponding array

Tags: typescript

```
type AnimalName = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'bird'
const animal = {
  dog: { name: 'DC', bite: true },
  cat: { name: 'CC', fall: true },
  bird: { name: 'BC', pullShit: true }
}
function getAnimal (animalNames: Array<AnimalName>) {
  return animalNames.map(name => animal[name])
}
const [myCat, myBird] = getAnimal(['cat', 'bird'])
```

I obtained the following TypeScript type declaration:

```
myCat: {
    name: string;
    bite: boolean;
} | {
    name: string;
    fall: boolean;
} | {
    name: string;
    pullShit: boolean;
}
```

But I hope to directly obtain the correct type.

```
myCat = { name: 'CC', fall: true }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=86&pln=1&pc=1#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-bX+LJBGxAA)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't generate generic call signatures automatically, nor can `map()` be strongly-typed enough to automatically map a generic function to a tuple. You'll have to write the signature yourself and use a type assertion to have the compiler accept it.  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGGOXW) shows. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You used the const declaration for K, so the type can be confirmed, which is exactly what I wanted. I will investigate why this is the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work your function needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), so that the type of the output can depend on the type of the input.  So instead of giving `animalNames` the type `Array<AnimalName>`, it should be of some generic type parameter type `K` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Array<AnimalName>`.  That gives us

```
function getAnimal<K extends Array<AnimalName>>(animalNames: K) {
  return animalNames.map(name => animal[name]);
}
```

Of course you also care about the exact order and type of each element of `animalNames`, meaning you need `K` to be inferred as a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) and not an unordered array (a type like `Array<X | Y>` is not helpful to you; you want `[X, Y]`). TypeScript tends not to infer tuples unless given a hint; one way to give such a hint is to give the type parameter [a `const` modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters).  That gives us:

```
function getAnimal<const K extends Array<AnimalName>>(animalNames: K) {
  return animalNames.map(name => animal[name]);
}
```

Unfortunately we still aren't done.  TypeScript only understands that [the `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) produces an unordered array type, not a tuple. And it really won't be able to iterate over the elements of `K` and make the output depend on it. This is beyond TypeScript's abilities; see [Mapping tuple-typed value to different tuple-typed value without casts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218). The workaround is to just manually compute what that output type should be and [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that's what the function does.  And now that gives us

```
function getAnimal<const K extends Array<AnimalName>>(animalNames: K) {
  return animalNames.map(name => animal[name]) as
    { [I in keyof K]: typeof animal[K[I]] }
}
```

where the return type of `getAnimal()` is a [mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), turning each element of `K` (like `"cat"` and `"bird"`) into the corresponding [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) when using that as a key to `typeof animal` (using [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) because you haven't given type names to your animals).

And now, finally, we can test:

```
const [myCat, myBird] = getAnimal(['cat', 'bird']);
myCat
//^? const myCat: { name: string; fall: boolean; }
myBird
//^? const myBird: { name: string; pull: boolean; }
```

which produces the types you expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2A5FToF4oDkAJgPYDmBUAPoQMYrCU0EBGCATkQQFC0lwBnYFBSJUaKPgDe3KFFJkAXFClQ42CMoIARAMIEANFDbBNUYOwCu0AL4HZUesGWr1OLbv1GAZujTKLayg7BzZOFzUNLQAhLygwSzR-cytbbhtubm9LOFpgBH4oMghgeGR0AB4+QWEAaSgIAA9TOCIBWHZ2FBAKsvEsHAA+QYAKUXLMDQFlWoBKFQd2Est2OBExdAGIAQA6VDARtzxB9YmAbSOAXXmUAQc5VTOASSgENYBrCBASbyhay4C4AgP1O4jOtWel0uwXSvH4QigZyQIF0DCMyOiHCI0PwxVKGzQIzOBCchkIYS41wA3NxkajgNwAPSMgB6AH5HPDhHSGBEjsohOw3mQqVBfEllCwSCQ0BBRKKMhisUzWRzqgileEVJF3FBBcLRQkJcZpbL5TCgA)

Comment: You can also add `as const` after the `animal` object so that it will expect the actual values.