# TypeScript preserving Union Type after destructuring

Tags: typescript, destructuring, union-types

Consider the following TypeScript snippet:

```js
const entries = [["a", 1], ["b", 2]] as (["a", 1] | ["b", 2])[];
const mapped = entries.map((e) => e);
```

`entries` is typed as an array of a union of tuples.
`mapped` retains the type of `entries` as `(["a", 1] | ["b", 2])[]`.
However, when destructuring `e` in `Array.map` like so: ([Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=0&pretty=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmKAnAlnCMC8MDaOBEAhvgDQwCMAumQQEakwBMllMhGAFAcWVTAD6589MswCUOSgG4AUKEiwAtoQAOKuABMs8RKnQA6ZSo5cA1mQBulMVgB8uczCtsM86GKlA))

```js
// ...
const mapped = entries.map(([k, v]) => [k, v] as const);
```

`mapped` is now of type `["a" | "b", 1 | 2][]`, due to the way TypeScript handles unions.

How can I keep the intended output type like the input type?
How do I need to modify the type signature of `Array.map` (preferably) or the definition of the callback function itself to achieve this? I need to be able to apply strongly typed transformations to the output, say

```js
// ... import Uppercase<> ...
entries.map(([k, v]) => [k.toUpperCase(), v] as [Uppercase<typeof k>, typeof v]);`.
// expected: (["A", 1] | ["B", 2])[]
```

Comment: You're trying to do just the hard part of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66091118/2887218, which is still impossible. (The part of the answer starting "So let's step back and think" is the relevant bit) Just use a type assertion on your output.  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, thanks. Wasn't sure if this was outside of TypeScript's limitations. I think it would be valuable to keep the question up, since I was not able to find the linked answer myself. Voted to close.